# How to use printf to display off_t, nlink_t, size_t and other special types?

Tags: c, linux, printf, portability

In my program, I stat the files they want and send the data over. The fields of a stat `struct` are all special types:

```
struct stat {
  dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
  ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
  mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
  nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
  uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
  gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
  dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
  off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
  blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
  blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
  time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
  time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
  time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
};
```

The relevant code for my question follows:

```
len = snprintf( statbuf, STAT_BUFFER_SIZE,
  "%crwxrwxrwx %lu %u %u %lld %s %s\r\n",
  S_ISDIR( filestats.st_mode ) ? 'd' : '-',
  (unsigned long ) filestats.st_nlink,
  filestats.st_uid,
  filestats.st_gid,
  (unsigned long long ) filestats.st_size,
  date,
  filename);
```

How do I print these types in a portable and efficient way? At first I did it without casts by guessing the correct format specifiers. Apart from being an annoying programming habit, this also meant my code wouldn't work on a 32 bit system. Now with the casts it seems to work, but on how many platforms?

Comment: Specific for clock_t : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083142/what-s-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-clock-t

Comment: For `__uint128`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656241/how-to-print-uint128-t-number-using-gcc

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There isn't a fully portable way to do it, and it is a nuisance.

C99 provides a mechanism for built-in types like `size_t` with the `%zu` notation (and there are some extra, similar qualifiers).

It also provides the `<inttypes.h>` header with macros such as PRIX32 to define the correct qualifier for printing a 32-bit hexadecimal constant (in this case):

```
printf("32-bit integer: 0x%08" PRIX32 "\n", var_of_type_int32_t);
```

For the system-defined types (such as those defined by POSIX), AFAIK, there is no good way to handle them.  So, what I do is take a flying guess at a 'safe' conversion and then print accordingly, including the cast, which is what you illustrate in the question.  It is frustrating, but there is no better way that I know of.  In case of doubt, and using C99, then conversion to 'unsigned long long' is pretty good; there could be a case for using a cast to `uintmax_t` and PRIXMAX or equivalent.

Or, as [FUZxxl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417501/fuzxxl) [reminded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401526/how-to-use-printf-to-display-off-t-nlink-t-size-t-and-other-special-types/1401581?noredirect=1#comment48743557_1401581) me, you can use the modifier `j` to indicate a 'max' integer type.  For example:

```
printf("Maximal integer: 0x%08jX\n", (uintmax_t)var_of_type_without_format_letter);
```

Comment: Couldn't have said it better. Using (u)intmax_t and PRI(d|u)MAX (or equivalent) may be the best solution for most problematic system-defined types.

Comment: I already knew those macro's but they looked so ugly to me. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: They're ugly, but they're the nearest thing to portable that I know of.

Comment: btw, the format specifier for `size_t` should be `%zu` as `size_t` is an unsigned type...

Comment: Converting it yourself with e.g. `% (uid_t) 10` and `/= (uid_t) 10` is fully portable.

Comment: You might want to add that for `intmax_t`, the length modifier `j` exists, so you can use `%ju` to print an `uintmax_t` without using the bulky `inttypes.h` macros.

Answer (score 1):

> How to use printf to display `off_t`, `nlink_t`, `size_t` and other special types?

1. When the type has a matching print specifier, use that

   ```
   printf("Size is %zu\n", object_with_type_size_t);
   ```
2. When the type may lack a matching print specifier, yet the sign-ness is known, and is not an extended integer type, cast to the widest integer type.

   ```
   #include <inttypes.h>
   printf("PID is %jd\n", (intmax_t) object_with_type_pid_t);
   printf("INO is %ju\n", (uintmax_t) object_with_type_ino_t);
   ```
3. When the type may lack a matching print specifier, the sign-ness is unknown, and is not an extended integer type, cast to a widest integer type. [`nlink_t` sign-ness not specified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/systypes.h.html).  Use `uintmax_t` for portability. Use `intmax_t` for informative-ness.  Or use crafted code.

   ```
   printf("link is %ju\n", (uintmax_t) object_with_type_nlink_t);
   ```
4. When the integer type is an *extended integer* type, [`off_t` are  extended signed integral types](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/systypes.h.html), our options become trickier.   We could cast to `(u)intmax_t` like above and potentially truncate the value.  We could cast to a floating point type and potentially lose precision.  We could create crafted code.

   ```
   printf("link is %jd\n", (intmax_t) object_with_type_off_t );
   // or 
   printf("link is %.0Lf\n", (long double) object_with_type_off_t );
   // or 

   // off_t is a signed extended integer type
   #define OFF_DECIMAL_SIZE ((sizeof(off_t) * CHAR_BIT - 1)*28/93 + 3)
   char buf[OFF_DECIMAL_SIZE];
   printf("link is %s\n", prt_off(buf, object_with_type_off_t));
   ```

Supporting code

```
// off_t is a signed extended integer type
#define OFF_DECIMAL_STR_SIZE ((sizeof(off_t) * CHAR_BIT - 1)*28/93 + 3)

char* prt_off(char *dest, off_t off) {
  char buffer[OFF_DECIMAL_STR_SIZE];

  // Start filling from the end
  char *p = &buffer[sizeof buffer - 1];
  *p = '\0';

  // Work with negative values to well handle the min value
  off_t an = off < 0 ? off : -off;

  do {
    *(--p) = (char) ('0' - an % 10);
    an /= 10;
  } while (an);

  if (off < 0) {
    *(--p) = '-';
  }

  size_t size_used = &buffer[sizeof(buffer)] - p;
  return memcpy(dest, p, size_used);
}
```