# Use a #define in printf?

Tags: c++, string, c-preprocessor

I was wanting to use a constant of some kind for the application ID (so I can use it in printf).

I had this:

```
#define _APPID_ "Hello World!"
```

And then the simple printf, calling it into %s (string). It put this out:

`simple.cpp:32: error: cannot convert ‘_IO_FILE*’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int printf(const char*, ...)’`

What would I use to define the application ID to use in printf? I tried:

```
static const char _APPID_[] = "Hello World"`
```

but it didn't work, same error I think.

Comment: Would you please post the actual printf() line?  Also indicate what compiler you are using.

Comment: same error *"you think"*? It either is, or it isn't. You compiled the code, not us. If you don't know what errors you got, how do you expect others to?

Comment: `#define` and `printf()` ? Are you sure this is a C++ question?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you tried... but this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define _APPID_ "Hello world"

int main()
{
    printf("The app id is " _APPID_ "\n");
    /* Output: The app id is Hello world */
    return 0;
}
```

When presented with two constant strings back to back (i.e. `"hello " "world"`), the compiler treats them as a single concatenated constant string (`"hello world"`).

That means that in the case of trying to `printf` a compile-time constant string, you don't *need* to use `printf("%s", _APPID_)` (although that should still work).

Comment: Actually, do use `printf("%s", APP_ID)`. If you ever rename your app to "200% productivity booster", calling `printf(APP_ID)` wouldn't work too well.

Comment: If you are using PRIuPTR or other formatters from inttypes.h, printf("text " PRIuPTR "more text", 4); is the only way to go.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403074/printf-with-sizeof-on-32-vs-64-platforms-how-do-i-handle-format-code-in-platfor

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message, the problem is most likely not caused by the string constant, but by incorrect parameters given to `printf()`.

If you want to print to a file, you should use `fprintf()`, not `printf()`. If you want to print to the screen, use `printf()`, but don't give a file handle as its first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In source.h

```
#ifndef _SOURCE_H
#define SOURCE_H
#ifdef APP_ID
#define WHOAMI printf("%s\n", APP_ID);
#endif
#endif
```

In your program:

```
#define APP_ID __FILE__
#include "source.h"
int main()
{
    WHOAMI
    return 0;
}
```

the reason for this is to have a stadnard include file - source.h.  `__FILE__` inside a header file returns the name of the header file, so the APP_ID definition is constrained to live in the C file.

If you don't define APP_ID the code won't compile.

Answer (score -1):

`_APPID_` is a name that's reserved for the implementation. It matches the pattern `^_[A-Z].*`

Rename it to e.g. `APP_ID`.