# Why does printing a constant change the results of a single core / process application?

Tags: c

I have written a short (450 lines) program that calculates some situations that can actually occur in a Connect Four game. The program tries to build the game tree and it recognizes if a situation already occured (also I skip branches if only the symmetric version happened).

I count the number of times that I come to an situation that already happened with `int alreadyCounter`. But I've noticed something strange when executing:

Adding

```
printf("abcdefghijklm");
```

changes the result of my `alreadyCounter`!

I don't use other cores/ processes / threads. I compile the C-program with

```
gcc -g -W -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -o connectfour
```

The full source is at [GitHub](https://github.com/MartinThoma/connect-four/tree/master/C). (I'm sorry, I couldn't make the code significantly shorter)

Take a look at `connectfour.c` and `connectfour-strange.c`.
They only differ in line 386.

But they give - apart from many "abcdefghijklm" - different results:

connectfour:

```
[...]abcdefghijklmabcdefghijklm########################Finish:
Maximum of 20000 reached
alreadyCounter: 1547
mirroredCounter: 0
```

connectfour-strange:

```
[...]
########################Finish:
Maximum of 20000 reached
alreadyCounter: 1566
mirroredCounter: 0
```

**Why do I get different results on a single core / process / thread program when I only add some constant output?**

Comment: Sounds like a [heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

Comment: @FredLarson exactly, seems like a side effect of optimization to me.

Comment: connectfour.c does not even compile with your Makefile. I get `error: format '%i' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long unsigned int'`

Comment: `alreadyCounter` is of type `int` @Kylo

Comment: Nope. sizeof's "return type" is `size_t` which on my architecture (x64) is defined to `long unsigned int`. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403074/printf-with-sizeof-on-32-vs-64-platforms-how-do-i-handle-format-code-in-platfor

Comment: Sure, it is not. It's just a tip for future ;-)

Comment: Thank you, Kylo. I'm did not very often use C, so I'm happy about every hint I get :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I found your bug, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that is the cause for your observations, but in lines 334ff,

```
char mirrored[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];
for (int x = 0; x<BOARD_WIDTH; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y<BOARD_HEIGHT; y++) {
        mirrored[x+1-BOARD_WIDTH][y] = board[x][y];
    }
}
```

you write outside the allocated memory (your row index goes from `-(BOARD_WIDTH)` to `-1`), thus invoking undefined behaviour.

Also, that doesn't mirror the board. You very probably meant

```
mirrored[BOARD_WIDTH - 1 - x][y] = board[x][y];
```

there. Apart from that, I see no obvious candidates like out-of-bounds writes.

In `isBoardFinished` (line 43ff), you stop checking before you have reached row/column 0:

```
while (xTemp > 0)
```

(ditto for `y` in the top-down check, and both in the diagonals checks). That should be `x >= 0` to use the full board. But this could not overwrite `alreadyCounter`, still it may be useful.

But compiling the code with warnings turned on **and optimisations** shows the probable cause:

```
connect-four.c: In function ‘getFirstIndex’:
connect-four.c:202:19: warning: ‘index’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
connect-four.c: In function ‘getNewIndex’:
connect-four.c:202:19: warning: ‘index’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
connect-four.c:199:18: note: ‘index’ was declared here
connect-four.c: In function ‘getMyIndex’:
connect-four.c:202:19: warning: ‘index’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
connect-four.c:199:18: note: ‘index’ was declared here
connect-four.c: In function ‘makeTurns’:
connect-four.c:202:19: warning: ‘index’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
connect-four.c:199:18: note: ‘index’ was declared here
connect-four.c:202:19: warning: ‘index’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
connect-four.c:199:18: note: ‘index’ was declared here
```

So the warning and accompanying note (it appears multiple times with different function names but the same location due to inlining) tell us that it should be

```
unsigned int getFirstIndex(char board[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT]) {
    unsigned int index = 0;
    //               ^^^^^^^
```

to get deterministic results from invoking `getFirstIndex` with identical boards. Since you take the modulus with respect to `MAXIMUM_SITUATIONS` before returning an index, the returned index shouldn't be out of bounds, however, so no crash is to be expected as a consequence of that. But when you print out something, that may cause allocation on the stack (need not, the arguments and return address *could* be all passed in registers), and if it does, that can influence the bit-pattern at the place where `index` is allocated the next time `getFirstIndex` is called. That would change the returned value, and you look in the wrong slot in `database`, so you miss a previous occurrence of an identical board, thus you get fewer duplicates than if the value `getFirstIndex` produces *only* depends on the passed-in board (and not also on what bits happened to occupy a particular stack location).

Note that it is - with my version of gcc - necessary to have both, warnings tuned on and optimisations, to get the warning. My `clang` doesn't warn about it even with warnings and optimisations turned to the highest level. Other versions of gcc and clang, and other compilers may have different success in identifying the problem.

With `index` initialised to 0 in `getFirstIndex`, I get a consistent

```
########################Finish:
Maximum of 20000 reached
alreadyCounter: 4412
```

independent from whether the string is printed and the optimisation level. Without the initialisation, the value of `alreadyCounter` depends on both factors.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this error. I fixed it, but I still get the different behaviour :-(

Comment: I have just removed this code block, and the problem still occurs (however, your hint did help me, as I will add all lines of code again after I have found the bug that causes this strange behaviour)

Comment: Note that you have `mirrorBoard()` defined, you could just use that. I'm looking a bit further, have already found a further mistake (I think), but that one could not cause the change of `alreadyCounter`.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking at my code and helping me! It is astonishing how many errors can be done in such a simple program ... 
I'll give you a bounty in two days (by the moment I can't)

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this problem several times in my job of assistant in my school.

some students had their program segfaulting unless they added a printf somewhere.

Printf allocs some memory and does some crazy stuff with it.

My guess is that you have a buffer overflow somewhere, or you don't alloc enough memory for a structure, and printf erases it.

Try running valgrind to see if something goes wrong.

Comment: `valgrind -v ./connectfour-strange` gave me `218 errors from 18 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 7)` after setting `MAXIMUM_SITUATIONS` to two. Lets see if I can find the bug. Thanks for mentioning valgrind!

Comment: Wow, enjoy fixing all this ! If this is proved to be the problem, consider accepting the answer !

Comment: Is it possible that my functions (e.g. `unsigned int getFirstIndex(char board[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT])`) are the problem? I've used the array notation `char board[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT]` instead of `char** board` as I thought it would be easier to assign values to the array this way.

Comment: I've also added the output of [valgrind](https://github.com/MartinThoma/connect-four/blob/master/C/valgrind.txt). `Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation at 0x80488BC: getFirstIndex (connectfour-strange.c:207)` seems to be important, but I don't know what it means.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to go through 500 lines of code to find it, but it is almost always a memory issue.

Typically it is something like a stack corruption where you are indexing an array beyond the end, so the print statement modifies the stack and so the out of bounds access result is changed.

Run it through a tool like valgrind and it should help pinpoint the violation.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an instance of it, but that is a common result when using macros and passing something like i++ to it.
the `ABS(outcome)` is a macro that inserts the code
`(outcome) (outcome < 0 ? -outcome : outcome)`
if outcome is passed as i++, then you would get
`(i++) (i++ < 0 ? -i++ : i++)`

perhaps in the threaded version the macro is somehow getting rolled in by the compiler

Comment: `ABS` was defenitely not the problem. I removed it and the error still occurs.

Comment: @moose It didn't look like it, but its common enough to warrant a check.  Do you get the same problem if you compile without optimizations ... -O0.

Comment: Yes, I also get the error with -O0. I've just added it to the Makefile  to make sure that I don't get an error because of that. Thanks for mentioning it.