# %ld format conversion for portability

Tags: c++, x86, printf, 32bit-64bit, 16-bit

I have a code base which is intended to compile without warnings and run without any glitches on multiple architectures, all x86:  MSDOS, Windows 32 console mode, Windows 32 GUI mode, Linux 32, and Linux 64.

Before adding support of Linux 64, this was easy.  Almost all data were declared as either `int` or from the typedefs for BYTE, WORD, and DWORD:

```
typedef unsigned char   BYTE;
typedef unsigned short  WORD;
typedef unsigned long   DWORD;
```

Upon adding 64-bit gcc support, DWORD needed a little tweaking to remain as a 32 bit value since it represented stored data:

```
// to compile DWORDs as 32 bits on 64-bit machines:
#if __x86_64__
 typedef unsigned int    DWORD;
#else
 typedef unsigned long   DWORD;
#endif
```

And this worked nicely on all environments:

```
DWORD   data;
printf ("%lu", data);
```

However, `gcc -Wall` now complains about format conversions:

```
warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument
         1 has type ‘DWORD {aka unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
```

Due to the extensive formatting this code does—thousands of lines of output formatting—I'd rather not retrofit a type specific formatter.  A similar question was [answered by using the `z` modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524675/198536):

```
printf ("%zu", data);
```

But that makes Turbo C on MSDOS and Win32 console do something odd:  It shows the conversion specification `%zu` as output instead of converting anything.

Is there a cleaner way to handle the variability of the type in a way that goes with the grain of printf and the fundamental data types?

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403074/printf-with-sizeof-on-32-vs-64-platforms-how-do-i-handle-format-code-in-platfor ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your least-bad available option is to borrow conceptually from `<inttypes.h>`:

```
#ifdef _LP64
#define PRIdword  "d"
#define PRIudword "u"
#else
#define PRIdword  "ld"
#define PRIudword "lu"
#endif
```

and then

```
DWORD data;
printf("%"PRIdword, data);
```

This makes use of string constant concatenation, which all C90-compliant compilers should support.  Note that the correct macro to test is `_LP64`, not `__x86_64__`; that way it will Just Work when you go to port to some other LP64 system, or to the shiny new "x32" mode of Linux/x86-64 (32-bit pointers, wide registers).

It might not be a bad idea to invest in a wholesale conversion to the `<stdint.h>` types, but that won't get you out of this sort of thing, you'd just be writing

```
int32_t data;
printf("%"PRId32, data);
```

instead, and as far as I know most Windows compilers *still* don't have `<inttypes.h>`, sigh.

In case you're wondering, the `%` is not inside the macro so you can put format adjusters in if you want:

```
printf("%-32"PRIdword, data);
```

Comment: Yep.  I'll be doing something like this.  After carefully reevaluating the types in use, a little more than half can be changed to `int` or `long`.  There are only a few hundred that aren't so easily made generic, so I'll change them to format with `%s` and have a hand full of conversion to string functions, overloaded on the argument type.