# Finding the correct size of a struct from a pointer without creating an object?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, sizeof

Sorry if the title is confusing. Here's my *struct*:

```
struct l_list{
   int number;
   char *name;
   double value;
   struct l_list *next;
};

typedef struct l_list *PhoneBook;
```

Main function:

```
int main(void){

   printf("%u\n", sizeof(struct l_list));

   PhoneBook person1;

   printf("%u\n", sizeof(*person1));
   printf("%u\n", sizeof(PhoneBook));

   return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> 20
>     20
>     4

I understand that `PhoneBook` is showing 4 bytes because it's only the size of the *pointer*, but how can you find the size of the actual *struct* from the `typedef PhoneBook`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
printf("%u\n", sizeof(*(PhoneBook) NULL) );
```

Comment: `sizeof *(PhoneBook)NULL` will suffice, less parens :)

Comment: Could you explain how/what the brackets around `PhoneBook` are doing? Are you defining a NULL object, then dereferencing it..?

Comment: @tgun926 It is [casting](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm) to `PhoneBook`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof( *(PhoneBook)NULL ) );
```

the important question is why is the above valid, aren't you performing *indirection* on a `NULL` *pointer* which would be [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)? No, you are not since `sizeof` with the exception of [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) is not evaluated at all. If we look at the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.3.4` *The sizeof operator* paragraph *2* says(*emphasis mine*):

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand. The result is an integer. **If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated** and the result is an integer constant.

furthermore we see the following example in paragraph *5* which confirms this reading:

```
double *dp = alloc(sizeof *dp);
```

At compile time the *type* of the expression with be determined in order to compute the result. We can further demonstrate this with the following example:

```
int x = 0 ;
printf("%zu\n", sizeof( x++ ));
```

which won't increment `x`.

**Note**: `%zu` is a [platform independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403074/printf-with-sizeof-on-32-vs-64-platforms-how-do-i-handle-format-code-in-platfor) format specifier for the result of `sizeof`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
typedef struct l_list{
    int number;
    char *name;
    double value;
   struct l_list *next;
} PhoneBook, *PPhoneBook;
```

Then your PhoneBook is an typedef for struct l_list, rather than the pointer. This makes more sense. PPhoneBook (or any other name of your choice) is typedef for Phonebook *.

Then you can do:

```
sizeof(PhoneBook)
```

and it will give you the correct size of a PhoneBook object.

Or you can do:

```
sizeof(PPhoneBook)
```

and it will return 4 bytes, the pointer size. Note that hiding the fact that you're using a pointer behind a non-pointer-looking typedef (such as PPhoneBook) is not always advisable. It can make your code confusing. However, if that's what you want, this is how to do it!

Comment: But then whenever I define an object I will have to do `PhoneBook *person3;` i.e. specify it's a pointer, won't I?

Comment: You can create multiple typedefs in a single statement if you want to typedef the pointer too - see edit above.

Comment: Hiding indirection in typedef's is a bad idea. You can't look at a type name and figure out if it's a pointer, or double pointer, or what. The extra * in the declaration is only a single character more and makes it very clear the variable is a pointer and not a struct.

Comment: @Charlie Burns: In general, I would agree. However, the OP seems to have a specific wish for a typedef with hidden indirection. Hence the suggestion above. I'll update my answer with your point though.

Comment: @Baldrick, my comment was directed at OP, not at your answer. I should have made that clear. Sorry.

Comment: @Charlie Burns - No worries :)