# printf format specifiers for uint32_t and size_t

Tags: c, printf

I have the following

```
size_t   i = 0;
uint32_t k = 0;

printf("i [ %lu ] k [ %u ]\n", i, k);
```

I get the following warning when compiling:

```
format ‘%lu’ expects type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument has type ‘uint32_t’
```

When I ran this using splint I got the following:

```
Format argument 1 to printf (%u) expects unsigned int gets size_t: k
```

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: C89 does not support `uint32_t` from `<stdint.h>` or `<inttypes.h>`; if you want to use those types, you should upgrade to C89.  As an extension, it is likely that GCC does allow you to use them, but C89 did not have any such support.

Comment: And the official C99 format modifier for `size_t` is 'z', as in `"%zu"`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401526/how-to-use-printf-to-display-off-t-nlink-t-size-t-and-other-special-types

Comment: I believe @kenny's answer is best for `uint32_t`, but it lacks `size_t`. @u0b34a0f6ae's answer includes both.

Comment: 2nd mention of C89 in 1st comment by Jonathan Leffler should be C99

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Sounds like you're expecting `size_t` to be the same as `unsigned long` (possibly 64 bits) when it's actually an `unsigned int` (32 bits). Try using `%zu` in both cases.

I'm not entirely certain though.

Comment: No warnings when compiling. However, running splint I get the following: 
1) printf (%u) expects unsigned int gets uint32_t: i 
2) printf (%u) expects unsigned int gets size_t: k

Comment: Sounds like splint is just being pedantic, then. It's probably going off the names of types in the source code and doesn't realize they're equivalent. I wonder what it would do with @KennyTM's answer... It certainly should be more portable.

Comment: splint is actually doing the right thing. Just because `int32_t` happens to be `int` on your compiler/platform doesn't mean it might not be `long` on another. Same for `size_t`. It's actually going out of its way and doing **more** work to detect this portability bug since the easy, natural check would be to just honor the typedef like the compiler does.

Comment: -1, sorry it's not portable. All that's needed is that the format specifiers and the types agree, and you can always cast to make that true. long is at least 32bits, so `%lu` together with `(unsigned long)k` is always correct. `size_t` is trickier, which is why `%zu` was added in C99. If you can't use that, then treat it just like `k` (`long` is the biggest type in C89, `size_t` is very unlikely to be larger).

Answer (score 164):

Try

```
#include <inttypes.h>
...

printf("i [ %zu ] k [ %"PRIu32" ]\n", i, k);
```

The `z` represents an integer of length same as `size_t`, and the `PRIu32` macro, [defined in the C99 header `inttypes.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inttypes.h), represents an unsigned 32-bit integer.

Comment: Compiles with no warnings. But splint doesn't like it. Unrecognized format code: %zu. And for the second one. Parse Error. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help
             parseerrors.)
*** Cannot continue.

Comment: @robUK: Heh. I suggest you file a bug for splint.

Comment: This is the right answer. Though my personal recommendation is to simply cast, e.g. `printf( "%lu", (unsigned long )i )`. Otherwise one ends up later with pile of warnings all over the code due to a type change.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I agree with KennyTM about filing a bug for splint.

By the way, "%zu" is the proper format for size_t. You don't need any of the PRI* macros for printing size_t.

Comment: If I remember correctly %zu is C99, and in the question he wrote 'C89'.

Comment: @alcor yes he did put C89 (apparently the gcc compiler flag he's using) but he is using `uint32_t` so actually it is C99 code, and should be compiled as such.

Answer (score 33):

All that's needed is that the format specifiers and the types agree, and you can always cast to make that true. `long` is at least 32 bits, so `%lu` together with `(unsigned long)k` is always correct:

```
uint32_t k;
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)k);
```

`size_t` is trickier, which is why `%zu` was added in C99. If you can't use that, then treat it just like `k` (`long` is the biggest type in C89, `size_t` is very unlikely to be larger).

```
size_t sz;
printf("%zu\n", sz);  /* C99 version */
printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)sz);  /* common C89 version */
```

If you don't get the format specifiers correct for the type you are passing, then `printf` will do the equivalent of reading too much or too little memory out of the array. As long as you use explicit casts to match up types, it's portable.

Answer (score 20):

If you don't want to use the PRI* macros, another approach for printing **ANY** integer type is to cast to `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t` and use `"%jd"` or `%ju`, respectively. This is especially useful for POSIX (or other OS) types that don't have PRI* macros defined, for instance `off_t`.