# Pointer in C, don't understand how they got this result

Tags: c, pointers, casting

```
main(){
 char i[2];
 * i = 0;
 * (i + 1) = 1;
 printf("len = %d \n",sizeof(int *));  
 printf("i[0] = %d \n",*(int *)i); 
}
```

where the answer is not 16 the answer is 256
i use the turboc2.0 the hex is 100

Comment: Why the answer should be 16? and also, I never experienced **two** `printf()`s producing **one** answer.

Comment: Is the answer maybe 100 in hex, i.e. 0x100?

Comment: Predicting what this code does is pointless. It's all implementation specific and quite possibly UB too. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's even worse on 64-bit.

Comment: i use turboc2 the the sizeof(int *) is 2 byte i is the array  address

Comment: I can't help getting the feeling OP just bashed on his keyboard at random, without even remotely knowing/understanding what a pionter, an array and a type is

Comment: Why do you use `main()`?

Comment: Why is the answer not 16? Because `CHAR_BITS != 4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code depends on your system, specifically on the size of an int.

After initializing, your `i` array looks like this:

```
 ------------
|0x00 | 0x01 |
 ------------
```

**Assumed an `int` is 32 bits** on your system:

When casting `i` to an `*int` and dereferencing it, there will be four bytes which are accessed (since an `int` is 32 bits or four bytes):

```
 --------------------------
|0x00 | 0x01 | 0x?? | 0x?? |
 --------------------------
```

So, the last two bytes are out of bounds of your array, will have any value, and you will observe undefined behavior (on my system, actually, it prints different values each time I execute the code, like `1762656512`, `-375848704`, ...).

**Assumed an `int` is 16 bits** on your system, it gets a littlebit "better":

In this case, when casting `i` to an `*int` and dereferencing it, the two bytes will be accessed as a 16 bit value. But, it then still depends on the [**endianess**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) which value you get:

- Little endian: `*(int*) i = 0x0100 = 256`
- Big endian: `*(int*) i = 0x0001 = 1`

So, if you expect `256`, you need to make sure to be on a little endian 16 bit system ...

BTW: When using `sizeof()` with `printf()`, make sure to [use the `%zu` format specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168275/printf-format-specifiers-for-uint32-t-and-size-t).

Comment: And using `%d` for `sizeof` adds cherry on cake.

Comment: i understand this i mistake the byte, one byte equal 8 bit,one hex equal 4 bit, it's big mistake,thanks   @Andreas