# How to get size_t from string?

Tags: c, string, size-t

I need to get an array size from user input. It seemed natural to me to store the input as `size_t`, however looking for an appropriate `strto...()` function I couldn't find any. I just used `strtoull()`, since `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits and I'm using C99 anyway. But I was wondering what would be the best way to get `size_t` from a string - say, in ANSI C.

Edit:

To clarify, I don't want the string length! The user will input the size of a large buffer in the form of a string, for instance `"109302393029"`. I need to get that number and store as `size_t`. Of course I could use `strtol()` or even `atoi()`, but it seems like a clumsy hack (`size_t` may hold larger values than `int`, for instance, and I want the user to be able to input any value in the addressable space).

Comment: `strlen` will not work for a pointer to an array.

Comment: You could use `unsigned long long` as the variable type. Seems unlikely that `size_t` would be larger than that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [printf format specifiers for uint32\_t and size\_t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168275/printf-format-specifiers-for-uint32-t-and-size-t)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In case you have a *string* input containing the value for a `size_t` and you want to get the value, you can use [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) with `%zu` format specifier to read the value and store it into corresponding `size_t` variable.

*Note: do not forget to check the success of `sscanf()` and family*.

Pseudo-code:

```
size_t len = 0;
if (1 == sscanf(input, "%zu", &len))
printf("len is %zu\n", len);
```

However, FWIW, this won't handle the overflow case. In case of the input length being *arbitaryly large* which your program should be able to handle, you may want to make use of [`strtoumax()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoumax) and check for overflow, finally casting the returned value to `size_t`. Please see [Mr. Blue Moon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1275169/blue-moon)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32325861/2173917) related to this.

---

However, if you don't mind another approach, instead of taking the input as *sting* and converting it to `size_t`, you can directly take the input as `size_t`, like

```
size_t arr_size = 0;
scanf("%zu", &arr_size);
```

Comment: He could also take the input as string and then use `sscanf`

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it's not safe against integer overflow, considering OP wants to handle arbitrarily large inputs.

Comment: @BlueMoon Sir, I think you meant _unsafe_, and that's very true. Range checking is needed in case of over/underflow. I'll add a paragraph about `strtoumax()` in my answer. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: Yes. I have already added an answer with `strtoumax` approach.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`strtoumax()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtoimax.3.html) to perform the conversion:

```
   #include <inttypes.h>

   intmax_t strtoimax(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
   uintmax_t strtoumax(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

and cast the result to size_t. This is a better approach since it helps detect overflow when arbitrarily large input is given.

The `scanf()` family functions can't detect integer overflow, which results in [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: "... and cast the result to size_t." omits detecting overflow when `SIZE_MAX < UINTMAX_MAX`.  It also does not detect a negative entry.

Answer (score 2):

Just get the input as unsigned int and cast it to size_t, or just:

```
size_t length;
scanf("%zu", &length);
```

Comment: He is using `c99` so specifier `'%zu'` will be more suited for `size_t`.