# Format specifiers for data type BYTE, WORD and DWORD in c-language?

Tags: c, filesystems, format-specifiers, fat32, fat

In C-language, what are the most appropriate format specifiers for data type BYTE, WORD and DWORD to be used with printf and scanf functions?
I am having a hard time displaying BPB field's values over console.

For example, if I am trying to display BPB_BytsPerSec using "%lu", I am getting unusual figures..

```
printf("Bytes per Sector: %lu", b->BPB_BytsPerSec);
```

I am getting a value of "514", which I believe, is wrong interpretation.. Please suggest the way out. Thanks.

(I am using gcc 5.1 via MinGW, over a 64bit Windows)

Here is the Structure We are  talking about:

```
/* BPB Structure Collected from internet */
struct BPB_FAT32 {
  BYTE  BS_jmpBoot[3];      // 0  
  BYTE  BS_OEMName[8];      // 3  
  WORD  BPB_BytsPerSec;     // 11 
  BYTE  BPB_SecPerClus;     // 13 
  WORD  BPB_ResvdSecCnt;    // 14 
  BYTE  BPB_NumFATs;        // 16 
  WORD  BPB_RootEntCnt;     // 17 
  WORD  BPB_TotSec16;       // 19 
  BYTE  BPB_Media;          // 21
  WORD  BPB_FATSz16;        // 22
  WORD  BPB_SecPerTrk;      // 24
  WORD  BPB_NumHeads;       // 26
  DWORD BPB_HiddSec;        // 28
  DWORD BPB_TotSec32;       // 32
  DWORD BPB_FATSz32;        // 36
  WORD  BPB_ExtFlags;       // 40
  WORD  BPB_FSVer;          // 42
  DWORD BPB_RootClus;       // 44
  WORD  BPB_FSInfo;         // 48
  WORD  BPB_BkBootSec;      // 50
  BYTE  BPB_Reserved[12];   // 52
  BYTE BS_DrvNum;           // 64
  BYTE BS_Reserved1;        // 65
  BYTE BS_BootSig;          // 66
  DWORD BS_VolID;           // 67
  BYTE BS_VolLab[11];       // 71
  BYTE BS_FilSysType[8];    // 82
};
```

And this the function through which i am trying to display these values..

```
void DisplayBlock(struct BPB_FAT32* b){

    printf("\n\n\t1.  Jump to boot code..........: 0x%02x%02x%02x",b->BS_jmpBoot[0],b->BS_jmpBoot[1],b->BS_jmpBoot[2]);
    printf("\n\n\t2.  OEM name & version.........: "); for(int i=0; i<8;i++) printf("%c",(char)b->BS_OEMName[i]);
    printf("\n\n\t3.  Bytes per Sector...........: %u",b->BPB_BytsPerSec);      // WORD
    printf("\n\n\t4.  Sectors per Cluster........: %lu", b->BPB_SecPerClus);    // BYTE
    printf("\n\n\t5.  Reserved Sectors Count.....: %lu", b->BPB_ResvdSecCnt);   // WORD
    printf("\n\n\t6.  Number of FAT32 tables.....: %u", b->BPB_NumFATs);        // BYTE
    printf("\n\n\t7.  Number of Root Entries.....: %lu", b->BPB_RootEntCnt);    // WORD
    printf("\n\n\t8.  Total Sectors 16bits.......: %lu",b->BPB_TotSec16);       // WORD
    printf("\n\n\t9.  Media Descriptor...........: %lu",b->BPB_Media);          // BYTE   0xF8 is the standard value for fixed media
    printf("\n\n\t10. Size According to FAT16....: %lu",b->BPB_FATSz16);        // WORD
    printf("\n\n\t11. Number of Sector per Track.: %lu",b->BPB_SecPerTrk);      // WORD
    printf("\n\n\t12. Number of Heads............: %lu",b->BPB_NumHeads);       // WORD
    printf("\n\n\t13. Number of Hidden Sectors...: %lu", b->BPB_HiddSec);       // DWORD
    printf("\n\n\t14. Total Sectors 32bits.......: %lu", b->BPB_TotSec32);      // DWORD
    /* FAT32 Specific Fields Starting offset:36 */
    printf("\n\n\t15. Size According to FAT32....: %lu", b->BPB_FATSz32);       // DWORD
    //printf("\n\n\t16. Extended Flags............: %u",b->BPB_ExtFlags);       // WORD  Usually 0.
    printf("\n\n\t17. File System Version........: %lu", b->BPB_FSVer);         // WORD         Must be 0:0
    printf("\n\n\t18. Root Cluster Number........: %lu",b->BPB_RootClus);       // DWORD        Usually 2
    printf("\n\n\t19. File System Information....: %lu",b->BPB_FSInfo);         // WORD
    printf("\n\n\t20. Backup Boot Sector.........: %lu",b->BPB_BkBootSec);      // WORD         Recomended 6
    //  BYTE  BPB_Reserved[12]  
    /* Remaining common fields FAT12/FAT16 BPB*/
    printf("\n\n\t21. Drive Number...............: %u",b->BS_DrvNum);           // BYTE
    //  BYTE BS_Reserved1;      /* 65 reserved          */
    printf("\n\n\t22. Boot Signature.............: %u",b->BS_BootSig);          // BYTE
    printf("\n\n\t23. Volume ID..................: %lu",b->BS_VolID);           // DWORD
    printf("\n\n\t24. Volume Lable...............: %s",b->BS_VolLab); //for(int i=0;i<11;i++) printf("%c",b->BS_VolLab[i]);     // BYTE [11]
    printf("\n\n\t25. File System Type...........: "); for(int i=0;i<8;i++) printf("%c",b->BS_FilSysType[i]);  // BYTE [8]
}
```

And here is the unhappy output :
[image: a Sample output]

Comment: How about casting? `printf("%"PRIu16, (uint16_t)b->BPB_BytsPerSec);` (include `inttypes.h` to use these macros)

Comment: BPB_BytsPerSec is a WORD (aka unsigned short).  Integer promotion makes it a 32-bit value and *long* is surely a 32-bit value on your compiler as well so %lu is not horribly wrong.  But sure, 514 can't be right.  Off-by-2 does not leave a reasonable guess how this went wrong.

Comment: Why 514 is retrieved: Where is read for `b->BPB_BytsPerSec` may be wrong or there may be extra padding in the structure (there are 11 bytes before `BPB_BytesPerSec` and what is after `BPB_BytesPerSec` is `BPB_SecPerClus`, which may be 2).

Comment: @MikeCAT, thanks Mike, but still 514

Comment: Would you mind posting the link the official documentation about this structure?

Comment: Are you using a `packed` struct?

Comment: @2501, Oops, my bad, here, hope this will work: [link](https://staff.washington.edu/dittrich/misc/fatgen103.pdf)

Comment: @WeatherVane, Nope. Just a plain structure.

Comment: Please post the structure too. Why would disk bytes per sector be a `long`? What number are you expecting? What is the endianness?

Comment: What is the definition of the struct containing member `BPB_BytsPerSec`, i.e. what type is that member?

Comment: @WeatherVane,Here is the Structure, sorry for an untidy code :)

Comment: @2501, Here is the Structure. Sorry for an untidy code :)

Comment: It needs to be a `packed` struct. You don't need any `l` in the format specifier, just `%u`, and you need to check out the endianness to make sure the (typical) sector size is `0x0200` and not `0x0002`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, i think , correctness of first three bytes assures i dont have endianness problem.

Comment: No, endianness does not apply to character arrays, it applies to integer types. Always assume, that with externally supplied data, that you *might* have an endianness issue. And the first 3 bytes being right does not say you don't need to make it a `packed` struct. Why are you asking a question if you are going to deny the answers?

Comment: If you want, defien the whole thing as a byte array, and build each field from that, according to endianness. Make sure you have an `unsigned char` array.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I am not denying the answer, i am trying it as you said :)

Comment: Assuming `unsigned char fat[...]`, and `unsigned bytespersector`, you can get bigendian `bytespersector = fat[11] * 256 + fat[12]`, or littlendian `bytespersector = fat[12] * 256 + fat[11]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, attributing structure as packed, opened a whole new family of compilation errors for "incompatible pointer dereferencing".. I shall try sorting them out tomorrow. Anyway, thanks a lot for pointing this mistake. 

Comment: Why not go with the byte array? You *must* deal with the endian issue, in general.

Comment: @WeatherVane, BYTE array is good, i want some cherry picking :)

Comment: Regarding the endianness: fat is by design using little endianness for (almost all of) its headers. x86 and x86-64 use little endian, too. So unless you're using a bit more "exotic" hardware (AVR32 for example, some ARM chips depending on their configuration) endianness is not your issue. Though of course one should strive to keep their code portable.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
typedef unsigned long long QWORD;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's make something that's going to be portable enough and that gives us a compiler warning when it turns out it is being used in a place where assumptions no longer hold.

First, we need to see how these types are defined. On my 64bit machine

```
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\minwindef.h

typedef unsigned long       DWORD;
typedef unsigned char       BYTE;
typedef unsigned short      WORD;
```

Now, what's the situation on 32bit?

According to this linked MSDN page, the definitions are still the same, so the differences in size come from the fact that `long` etc. are of different size on a 32bit Windows, not not from any different definition of DWORD, etc. themselves. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

Therefore, the problem is, how do we portably print an `unsigned long`, etc.? There are serveral answers that C99 gives us.

### PRI macros

First, there are the `PRIxxx` macros defined in <inttypes.h>. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

### Length modifiers

Interesting length modifiers were added to [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) in C99. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/99

They can be used in Visual Studio, assuming you have sufficiently new version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-170

- `z` length modifier for `size_t` and its signed version
- `t` length modifier for `ptrdiff_t` and its unsigned version
- `j` length modifier for `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`

For `WORD`, which is `unsigned short`, the modifier is `h`, so use `%hu`.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

```
printf("\n\n\t3.  Bytes per Sector...........: %hu",b->BPB_BytsPerSec);      // WORD
```

### Rely on implicit promotions

When an integer type smaller than int is given as a parameter to a variadic function (which printf is), it is promoted to int or unsigned int. So, you can just print a WORD like it was an int to begin with. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion

### Cast to `intmax`

Cast to `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t` and then use `%jd` or `%ju`, respectively. This will work every time, because `intmax` are the largest possible types on the system. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3171743/1047788

```
printf("\n\n\t13. Number of Hidden Sectors...: %ju", (uintmax_t)b->BPB_HiddSec);       // DWORD
```