# BYTE, WORD and DWORD macros definition

Tags: c

I am trying to understand, what would be the best way to define `BYTE`, `WORD` and `DWORD` macros, which are mentioned in answers of this [question](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?302806-what-is-HIBYTE-LOBYTE-HIWORD-LOWORD).

> ```
> #define LOWORD(l) ((WORD)(l))
> #define HIWORD(l) ((WORD)(((DWORD)(l) >> 16) & 0xFFFF))
> #define LOBYTE(w) ((BYTE)(w))
> #define HIBYTE(w) ((BYTE)(((WORD)(w) >> 8) & 0xFF))
> ```

Would it be correct to assume, that:

- `BYTE` is macro defined as
  `#define BYTE __uint8_t`
- `WORD` is macro defined as
  `#define WORD __uint16_t`
- `DWORD` is macro defined as
  `#define DWORD __uint32_t`

If yes, why cast to another macro instead of casting to `__uint8_t`, `__uint16_t` or `__uint32_t`? Is it written like that to increase clarity?

I also found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283855/format-specifiers-for-data-type-byte-word-and-dword-in-c-language) which answers include `typedef`, with little bit more of *research* I've found answers to [question about comparing `#define` and `typedef`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666353/are-typedef-and-define-the-same-in-c#1666375). Would `typedef` be better to use in this case?

Comment: You can do what you like. They’re names used on Windows. The names like `__uint8_t` are wholly non-standard.  Whether they do what you want is at the whim of the compiler.

Comment: Instead of using __uint8_t, __uint16_t or __uint32_t you may include `stdint.h` and use uint8_t, uint16_t or uint32_t which [conform the standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).

Comment: These are typedefs from the Windows SDK, they isolate the winapi from the C compiler implementation and processor architecture.  Your #defines look fine.  The macros you posted are simple crackers to lift an 8-bit or 16-bit value from a larger integral type, SendMessage() in particular requires a lot of crunching to fit message arguments in the two parameters it takes.  The kind of economy that mattered 30 years ago when they had to shoehorn a GUI into a quarter megabyte of memory.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but how about compilers like GNU GCC used in GNU/Linux environment?

Comment: @HansPassant, I couldn't mention two users in one comment, therefore I ask you to read my previous comment.

Comment: What about GCC?  The double-underscore names are reserved for use by the implementation for any purpose.  They are not mandated by any standard.  What you have will work on a GCC (and Clang because it emulates GCC), but other compilers are not required to recognize the types.

Comment: I don't see the real question, maybe you just didn't try it yet.  If you meant to target Windows with GCC then you should not write these yourself.  Use MinGW-w64 instead.  You'll at least need the link libraries it supplies, you get the macros for free with a standard #include.

Comment: @HansPassant I was experimenting with [online C compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php) and `BYTE` and others appeared as undefined, therefore I was interested, how that should be defined.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a portable solution:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t DWORD;   // DWORD = unsigned 32 bit value
typedef uint16_t WORD;    // WORD = unsigned 16 bit value
typedef uint8_t BYTE;     // BYTE = unsigned 8 bit value
```

Comment: And for BOOL it should be "typedef int32_t BOOL;"

Comment: So uint8_t is the same as BYTE?

Comment: @bluejayke yes it should be, but n`BYTE` is not a standard type. It's standard only for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You have it defined at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx, and that is already defined in Windows Data Type headers for WinAPI:

```
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
```

and it is a type, and not a macro.

Comment: Those typedefs won't necessarily be correct with other compilers (e.g. `DWORD` is assumed to be 32 bits but `unsigned long` may be larger on non-Microsoft compilers).