# Converting uint32_t to binary in C

Tags: binary, converters, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32, uint32-t

The main problem I'm having is to read out values in binary in C. Python and C# had some really quick/easy functions to do this, I found topic about how to do it in C++, I found topic about how to convert int to binary in C, but not how to convert uint32_t to binary in C.

What I am trying to do is to read bit by bit the 32 bits of the DR_REG_RNG_BASE address of an ESP32 (this is the address where the random values of the Random Hardware Generator of the ESP are stored).

So for the moment I was doing that:

```
#define DR_REG_RNG_BASE                        0x3ff75144

void printBitByBit( ){

    // READ_PERI_REG is the ESP32 function to read DR_REG_RNG_BASE
    uint32_t rndval = READ_PERI_REG(DR_REG_RNG_BASE);
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 32; i++){ 
      int mask =  1 << i;
      int masked_n = rndval & mask;
      int thebit = masked_n >> i;   
      Serial.printf("%i", thebit);
    }
    Serial.println("\n");
}
```

At first I thought it was working well. But in fact it takes me out of binary representations that are totally false. Any ideas?

Comment: The bits are at positions 0 thru 31, not 1 thru 32.

Comment: An expression for the bit from position `i` is simply `rndval >> i & 1`. Print them in order from position 31 to position 0, inclusive.

Comment: So, I've finally found the nice function bitRead() https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/bits-and-bytes/bitread/

It gives me the exact same result as my mask.

Comment: About 0 to 31, it's been a nightmare. I did many tests and the loop must start from 1 not from 0.  Since bitRead() give me the very same results ( 00100000000000000000000000000000 to represents uint32_t = 8), I guess it's just correct and the ESP32 just do it like that.

Comment: The output in your last comment is **4** backwards (see my answer for why its  backwards); if it were **8** backwards, it would start with `0001`. So, you're dropping the lowest bit, there.

Comment: @loulou: `bitRead` gave you the same results as your code because you didn't fix your indices. The indices are the problem, not the masking. The fact that calling `bitRead` with wrong inputs gave the same result as using your masking code with wrong inputs doesn't mean the inputs were actually right.

Answer (score 1):

Your shown code has a number of errors/issues.

First, bit positions for a `uint32_t` (32-bit unsigned integer) are **zero-based** – so, they run from 0 thru 31, not from 1 thru 32, as your code assumes. Thus, in your code, you are (effectively) ignoring the lowest bit (bit #0); further, when you do the `1 << i` on the last loop (when `i == 32`), your mask will (most likely) have a value of zero (although that shift is, technically, undefined behaviour for a *signed* integer, as your code uses), so you'll also drop the highest bit.

Second, your code prints (from left-to-right) the *lowest* bit first, but you want (presumably) to print the *highest* bit first, as is normal. So, you should run the loop with the `i` index starting at 31 and *decrement* it to zero.

Also, your code mixes and mingles unsigned and signed integer types. This sort of thing is best avoided – so it's better to use `uint32_t` for the intermediate values used in the loop.

Lastly (as mentioned by Eric in the comments), there is a far simpler way to extract "bit n" from an unsigned integer: just use `value >> n & 1`.

I don't have access to an Arduino platform but, to demonstrate the points made in the above discussion, here is a standard, console-mode C++ program that compares the output of your code to versions with the aforementioned corrections applied:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t test = 0x84FF0048uL;
    int i;
    // Your code ...
    for (i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
        int mask = 1 << i;
        int masked_n = test & mask;
        int thebit = masked_n >> i;
        printf("%i", thebit);
    }
    printf("\n");
    // Corrected limits/order/types ...
    for (i = 31; i >= 0; --i) {
        uint32_t mask = (uint32_t)(1) << i;
        uint32_t masked_n = test & mask;
        uint32_t thebit = masked_n >> i;
        printf("%"PRIu32, thebit);
    }
    printf("\n");
    // Better ...
    for (i = 31; i >= 0; --i) {
        printf("%"PRIu32, test >> i & 1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The three lines of output (first one wrong, as you know; last two correct) are:

```
001001000000000111111110010000-10
10000100111111110000000001001000
10000100111111110000000001001000
```

---

Notes:

(1) On the use of the funny-looking `"%"PRu32` format specifier for printing the `uint32_t` types, see: [printf format specifiers for uint32_t and size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3168275/10871073).

(2) The cast on the `(uint32_t)(1)` constant will ensure that the bit-shift is safe, even when `int` and `unsigned` are 16-bit types; without that, you would get undefined behaviour in such a case.

Comment: 1) avoid UB `uint32_t mask = 1 << i;` --> `uint32_t mask = 1u << i;` or even better `uint32_t mask = (uint32_t)1 << i;`.   2) Better to use certain matching specifier `printf("%" PRIu32, thebit);` or the like - also in `printf("%u", test >> i & 1);`.

Comment: Adding the `u` suffix is certainly appropriate (and I would say better than the cast).

Comment: When `unsigned` is 16-bit, more than a `u` suffix  is needed.  (Also the issue with `printf()`s)  Could use `UINT32_C(1)` from `<stdint.h>`.  `UINTn_C()` macros are a bit unfamiliar, hence the `(uint32_t)1` idea.

Comment: @chux OK, you've convinced me. Now I'm off for a Scooby-Snack. :)

Comment: Candidate moral of the story: `(uint32_t)(1) << i` is a Scooby-doo and `1 << i` is a Scooby-don't?

Answer (score 0):

When you printing out a binary string representation of a number, you print the Most Signification Bit (MSB) first, whether the number is a uint32_t or uint16_t, so you will need to have a mask for detecting whether the MSB is a `1` or `0`, so you need a mask of `0x80000000`, and shift-down on each iteration.

```
#define DR_REG_RNG_BASE                        0x3ff75144

void printBitByBit( ){

    // READ_PERI_REG is the ESP32 function to read DR_REG_RNG_BASE
    uint32_t rndval = READ_PERI_REG(DR_REG_RNG_BASE);

    Serial.println(rndval, HEX);   //print out the value in hex for verification purpose

    uint32_t mask = 0x80000000;
    for (int i=1; i<32; i++) {
      Serial.println((rndval & mask) ? "1" : "0");
      mask = (uint32_t) mask >> 1;
    }
    Serial.println("\n");

}
```

For Arduino, there are actually a couple of built-in functions that can print out the binary string representation of a number. `Serial.print(x, BIN)` allows you to specify the number base on the 2nd function argument.

Another function that can achieve the same result is `itoa(x, str, base)` which is not part of standard ANSI C or C++, but available in Arduino to allow you to convert the number `x` to a `str` with number base specified.

```
char str[33];
itoa(rndval, str, 2);
Serial.println(str);
```

However, both functions does not pad with leading zero, see the result here:

```
36E68B6D                          // rndval in HEX
00110110111001101000101101101101  // print by our function
110110111001101000101101101101    // print by Serial.print(rndval, BIN)
110110111001101000101101101101    // print by itoa(rndval, str, 2)
```

BTW, Arduino is `c++`, so don't use `c` tag for your post. I changed it for you.