# How to compare nlink_t to int

Tags: c, file, parsing, variables

I use `stat` system call on Linux and retrieve file information.

```
char *parent_dir; // for example: /run/atd.pid/
struct stat buf;
stat(parent_dir, &buf);
```

**buf** structure type:

```
struct stat {
               dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
               ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
               mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
               nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
               uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
               gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
               dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
               off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
               blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for file system I/O */
               blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
               time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
               time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
               time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
           };
```

I get number of hard links like this: `buf.st_nlink`.

My problem is that I can't compare number of hard links to integer value. I've tried to initialize another **nlink_t** and then compare my variable to `stat` variable, but it doesn't work. I've also tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401526/use-printf-to-display-off-t-nlink-t-size-t-and-others).

Alternative way to cast **nlink_t** to **int**, but it doesn't work. always returns the same number.

```
int
parse_to_int(nlink_t *source)
{
  int buffer_size = sizeof(*source);
  char buffer[buffer_size];
  snprintf(&buffer[0], buffer_size, "%lu", (unsigned long)source);
  int val = atoi(buffer);
  return val;
}
```

Any idea?

Program output when I use `parse_to_int` function:

```
get stat for: /run/nm-dhclient-wlan0.conf/ 
nlink_t: 321
get stat for: /run/wpa_supplicant/ 
nlink_t: 321
get stat for: /run/udisks2/ 
nlink_t: 321
get stat for: /run/nm-dns-dnsmasq.conf/ 
nlink_t: 321
...
```

Comment: Can you not typecast the nlink_t to an int and use that?  or is there something else getting in the way?  Source for the failing case may help with questions.

Comment: The code isn't failing. If I try to get the value as described in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401526/use-printf-to-display-off-t-nlink-t-size-t-and-others) it always returns one number.

Comment: @gkiko: I don't get that behavior. Please show a minimal program that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nlink_t` is typedef'd as an integer type (e.g., `unsigned short` or `unsigned int`), so you should be able to cast `stat.st_nlink` to an `unsigned` or `unsigned long` without the compiler complaining.

Your `parse_to_int()` function is incorrect, because you're casting a pointer (`nlink_t*`) to an `unsigned int`, instead of the value of the `nlink_t` variable. But you don't need the function, just use the cast properly.

**Addendum**

Also make sure that you're not comparing an *unsigned* type to `-1`, which will give you unexpected results.

Comment: The problem was that I called `stat` on file ending with **/**. But I still have overflow problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I had several problems:

1. You can't get `stat` from file, if the path ends with `/`
2. There are some folders in your computer's folder list that are created by your operating system. Some kind of data in memory, interpreted as folders and files(called [virtual file-system](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html)). So if you try to get `i-node` number from this kind of file, you get some garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to compare to a uint. If you've got more than 64k hard links I'd be surprised.

Trying to guess the size it will take to print a string representation of a nlink_t from how many bytes long the nlink_t is a bug. nlink_t may be 8 bytes but 4000000000 is more than 8 bytes of digits printed out.

The right way to find exactly the right size is to check the return value of snprintf, it'll tell you how large a buffer was actually needed (or you could punt and allocate something larger than 8. sizeof(*source) isn't a solid solution.

```
int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%lu", (unsigned long)source);
buffer = new chara[size + 1]; //+1 for a NULL
int size = snprintf(buffer, size, "%lu", (unsigned long)source);
```

Also, the number of hard links should be consistent unless your file system is changing. Take a look at the output of

```
tmp]$ ls -ld /home/
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 4096 Feb  3  2012 /home/
```

That number before the owner is the number of hard links, 5 in this case.