# How to print types of unknown size like ino_t?

Tags: c, printf, portability

I often experience situations where I want to print with `printf` the value of an integer type of implementation-defined size (like `ino_t` or `time_t`). Right now, I use a pattern like this for this:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

ino_t ino; /* variable of unknown size */
printf("%" PRIuMAX, (uintmax_t)ino);
```

This approach works so far but it has a couple of disadvantages:

- I have to know whether the type I'm trying print is signed or unsigned.
- I have to use a type cast that possibly enlarges my code.

Is there a better strategy?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401526/use-printf-to-display-off-t-nlink-t-size-t-and-others

Comment: @MartinR - Regarding the similar question you referenced, Agree.  And the solution there is a perfect fit for this one too.  But this version of the question is asked in such a way as to present a much clearer presentation of the issue.  Too bad there is not an ethical way to post the content of the other answer here.

Comment: C++ offers a simple solution: `std::cout << ino ;`. The appropriate `<<` operator overload for the argument type will be used - no format specifiers necessary.  If there is no compelling reason to use C and this is a common need, C++ may be useful even if you are not intending to write OO code.  For the most part your C code need not change at all, except where C++ provides a better mousetrap - operator overloading in this case being one of them.

Comment: @Clifford: "Use a different language" is not a valid answer/advice for solving a problem in a given language. There are **a lot** of important C things that don't work in C++, and even if they do, idiomatic C code is anti-idiomatic C++, highly frowned upon as C++, and likely to produce lots of spurious warnings or errors (or worse yet, subtly different behavior) when treated as C++.

Comment: `_Generic` would be useful in this case - if you're willing to use C11.

Comment: @ryyker It's interesting. The accepted answer of the other question suggests to do the exact same thing I originally tried (i.e. casting to a large type [intmax_t] and using the formatting specifier for that [PRIiMAX]).

Comment: @FUZxxl - Yes, interesting.  The comment made by the answerer of that accepted answer: _It is frustrating, but there is no better way that I know of._ expresses similar concern you express in this question, i.e. that it can be done, but the method is not optimal.  I believe your stated question is presented very well.  Evidently, by the upclick count, others agree.

Comment: @R.. That's exactly why I did not post an *answer* - its a comment, a suggestion worth consideration - especially given the ugliness of the C solutions.  I think my suggestion was more moderated than you suggest;  I am not suggesting that all C code is valid C++, merely that using C++ does not necessitate a wholesale change of paradigm.

Comment: Personally, I'd use `"%ju"` rather than `"%" PRIuMAX`, just because I find the macro names in `<inttypes.h>` ugly and difficult to remember.

Comment: @KeithThompson Huch. I didn't even know about that. Would you make this an answer because it's definitely an improvement to the current situation.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Done (though it ended up a bit longer than I thought it would).

Comment: Question specific about `clock_t`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083142/what-s-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-clock-t

Comment: I don't think it is guaranteed that ino_t is integral, merely that it is arithmetic: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/types.h.html

Comment: @JamesYoungman Further down the text says that `ino_t` shall be an unsigned integer type.

Comment: @FUZxxl yes, but that is an XSI extension to POSIX.   Hence there will be (POSIX) systems where ino_t exists which are not XSI compliant, and for which therefore that constraint does not apply.

Comment: @JamesYoungman no, look again; the XSI tag is around the `fsbkcnt_t` and `fsfilcnt_t` types, not around the `ino_t` type, which must be an unsigned integer by POSIX.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <inttypes.h>
ino_t ino; /* variable of unknown size */
/* ... */
printf("%" PRIuMAX, (uintmax_t)ino);
```

That will certainly work (with some provisos; see below), but I'd use:

```
printf("%ju", (uintmax_t)ino);
```

The `j` length modifier

> Specifies that a following **`d`**, **`i`**, **`o`**, **`u`**,
>   **`x`**, or **`X`** conversion specifier applies to an **`intmax_t`**
>   or **`uintmax_t`** argument; or that a following **`n`** conversion
>   specifier applies to a pointer to an **`intmax_t`** argument.

There are also `z` and `t` modifiers for `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` (and their corresponding signed/unsigned types), respectively.

And personally, I find the format string macros defined in `<inttypes.h>` ugly and difficult to remember, which is why I prefer `"%ju"` or `"%jd"`.

As you mentioned, it's helpful to know whether the type (`ino_t` in this case) is signed or unsigned. If you don't happen to know that, it's possible to figure it out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define IS_SIGNED(type) ((type)-1 < (type)0)
#define DECIMAL_FORMAT(type) (IS_SIGNED(type) ? "%jd" : "%ju")
#define CONVERT_TO_MAX(type, value) \
    (IS_SIGNED(type) ? (intmax_t)(value) : (uintmax_t)(value))
#define PRINT_VALUE(type, value) \
    (printf(DECIMAL_FORMAT(type), CONVERT_TO_MAX(type, (value))))

int main(void) {
    ino_t ino = 42;
    PRINT_VALUE(ino_t, ino);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

though that may be overkill. If you're sure the type is narrower than 64 bits, you can convert the value to `intmax_t`, and the value will be preserved. Or you can use `uintmax_t` and get well-defined results for all values, though printing `-1` as `18446744073709551615` (2<sup>64</sup>-1) may be a bit confusing.

All of this works only if your C implementation supports `<stdint.h>` and the `j` length modifier for `printf` -- i.e., if it supports C99. Not all compilers do so (*cough*Microsoft*cough*). For C90, the widest integer types are `long` and `unsigned long`, and you can convert to those and use `"%ld"` and/or `"%lu"`. You can theoretically test for C99 compliance using the `__STDC_VERSION__` predefined macro -- though some pre-C99 compilers might still support types wider than `long` and `unsigned long` as an extension.

Comment: From my reading of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/types.h.html ino_t is guaranteed to be an arithmetic type but there is no guarantee it is an integral type.   Hence both PRIuMAX and PRIdMAX may be inappropriate.

Comment: @JamesYoungman: Farther down on the same page: "**`fsblkcnt_t`**, **`fsfilcnt_t`**,  and **`ino_t`** shall be defined as unsigned integer types."

Comment: Keith, that's an XSI extension, though.

Comment: @JamesYoungman It is only an XSI extension for fsblkcnt_t and fsfilcnt_t. For ino_t, it is always the case  that it is defined as unsigned integer type.

Answer (score 7):

Using C11 type generic macros, it is possible to construct the format string at compile time, e.g.:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRI3(B,X,A) _Generic((X), \
                             unsigned char: B"%hhu"A, \
                             unsigned short: B"%hu"A, \
                             unsigned int: B"%u"A, \
                             unsigned long: B"%lu"A, \
                             unsigned long long: B"%llu"A, \
                             signed char: B"%hhd"A, \
                             short: B"%hd"A, \
                             int: B"%d"A, \
                             long: B"%ld"A, \
                             long long: B"%lld"A)
#define PRI(X) PRI3("",(X),"")
#define PRIFMT(B,X,A) PRI3(B,(X),A),(X)

int main () {
    signed char sc = SCHAR_MIN;
    unsigned char uc = UCHAR_MAX;
    short ss = SHRT_MIN;
    unsigned short us = USHRT_MAX;
    int si = INT_MIN;
    unsigned ui = UINT_MAX;
    long sl = LONG_MIN;
    unsigned long ul = ULONG_MAX;
    long long sll = LLONG_MIN;
    unsigned long long ull = ULLONG_MAX;
    size_t z = SIZE_MAX;
    intmax_t sj = INTMAX_MIN;
    uintmax_t uj = UINTMAX_MAX;

    (void) printf(PRIFMT("signed char       : ", sc, "\n"));
    (void) printf(PRIFMT("unsigned char     : ", uc, "\n"));
    (void) printf(PRIFMT("short             : ", ss, "\n"));
    (void) printf(PRIFMT("unsigned short    : ", us, "\n"));
    (void) printf(PRIFMT("int               : ", si, "\n"));
    (void) printf(PRIFMT("unsigned int      : ", ui, "\n"));
    (void) printf(PRIFMT("long              : ", sl, "\n"));
    (void) printf(PRIFMT("unsigned long     : ", ul, "\n"));
    (void) printf(PRIFMT("long long         : ", sll, "\n"));
    (void) printf(PRIFMT("unsigned long long: ", ull, "\n"));
    (void) printf(PRIFMT("size_t            : ", z, "\n"));
    (void) printf(PRIFMT("intmax_t          : ", sj, "\n"));
    (void) printf(PRIFMT("uintmax_t         : ", uj, "\n"));
}
```

There is a potential problem, though: if there are types distinct from those listed (i.e., other than `signed` and `unsigned` versions of `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and `long long`), this does not work for those types. It is also not possible to add types such as `size_t` and `intmax_t` to the type generic macro "just in case", because it will cause an error if they *are* `typedef`d from one of the already listed types. I've left the `default` case unspecified so that the macro generates a compile-time error when no matching type is found.

However, as seen in the example program, `size_t` and `intmax_t` work just fine on platforms where they are the same as one of the listed types (e.g., same as `long`). Similarly there is no issue if, e.g., `long` and `long long`, or `long` and `int`, are the same type. But a safer version might be to just cast to `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t` according to signedness (as seen in other answers), and make a type generic macro with only those options…

A cosmetic problem is that the type generic macro expands with parentheses around the string literal, preventing concatenation with adjacent string literals in the usual way. This prevents things like:

```
(void) printf("var = " PRI(var) "\n", var); // does not work!
```

Hence the `PRIFMT` macro with prefix and suffix included for the common case of printing a single variable:

```
(void) printf(PRIFMT("var = ", var, "\n"));
```

(Note that it would be simple to expand this macro with the non-integer types supported by `printf`, e.g., `double`, `char *`…)

Answer (score 6):

The "size" of an integer type is not relevant here, but its range of values.

As apparently you tried, yet, it is possible to cast to `uintmax_t` and `intmax_t` to easily solve any ambiguity in the `printf()` call.

The issue of the signed or unsigned types can be solved in an easy way:

- All unsigned integer operations works modulo "N" for some positive value N, depending of the type. It implies that every result involving only unsigned integer types gives a nonnegative value.
- To detect if a variable `x` has a signed or an unsigned type, it is enough to verify if `x` and `-x` are both nonnegative values.

For example:

```
 if ( (x>=0) && (-x>=0) )
    printf("x has unsigned type");
 else
    printf("x has signed type");
```

Now, we can write some macros:

**(Edited: the name and expression of the macro have changed)**

```
 #include <inttypes.h>
 #include <limits.h>

 #define fits_unsigned_type(N) ( (N >= 0) && (  (-(N) >= 0) || ((N) <= INT_MAX) ) )
 #define smartinteger_printf(N) \
     (fits_unsigned_type(N)? printf("%ju",(uintmax_t)(N)): printf("%jd",(intmax_t) (N)) )
// ....
ino_t x = -3;
printf("The value is: "); 
smartinteger_printf(x);
//.....
```

**Note:** The signed or unsigned character of a variable is not well detected by the macro above when the value is 0. But in this case everything works well, because 0 has the same bit representation in signed or unsigned types.

The first macro can be used to detect if the underlying type of an arithmetical object has unsgined type or not.
This result is used in the second macro to choose the way in that the object is printed on screen.

**1st REEDITION:**

- As **Pascal Cuoq** pointed out in his comment, the integer promotions has to be taken in accont for unsigned `char` and `short` values fiiting in the range of `int`. This is equivalent to ask if the value is in the rango 0 to `INT_MAX`.

So I have changed the name of the macro to `fits_signed_type`.
Also, I have modified the macro to take in account the positive `int` values.

The macro `fits_unsigned_type` can tell if an object has unsigned integer type or not in most cases.

- If the value is negative, obviously the type is not `unsigned`.
- If the value N is positive then

  - if `-N` is positive, then N has `unsigned` type,
  - If `-N` is negative, but N is in the range 0 to `INT_MAX`, then the type of `N` could be `signed` or `unsigned`, but it would fit in the range of positive values of`int`, which fits in the range of `uintmax_t`.

**2nd REEDITION:**

Ir seems that there are here to approaches to solve the same problem. My approach takes in account the **range of values and integer promotion rules** to produce the correct printed value with `printf()`. On the other hand, Grzegorz Szpetkowski's approach determines the **signed character of a type** in straight form. I like both.

Comment: Your macro `has_unsigned_type` does not do what its name says for `unsigned char` and `unsigned short` when they contain only values that fit an `int`, but it does not prevent the function from working.

Comment: You are rignt. I figured out for the value 0, but poisitve values are in the same consideration. The macro is intended to detect "some" right choice in the `printf()` format string. I will add your comment, and probably change the name of the macro.

Comment: You can determine the signedness of an expression (of rank at least `int`) *without evaluating it* via `(1?-1:(expr))<0)`.

Comment: @R..: Nice. I didn't figure out such a simple solution.

Comment: Is `REEDITION` a real word?

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Yes, approved by google: [reedition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reedition)

Comment: @ryyker I think you mean *Google-esque*.

Answer (score 4):

Since your are already using  C99 header, there is a possibility to use exact width format specifier depending on `sizeof(T)` and signed/unsigned check. This however has to done after preprocessing phase (so sadly `##` operator cannot be used here to construct PRI token). Here is an idea:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

#define IS_SIGNED(T) (((T)-1) < 0) /* determines if integer type is signed */

...

const char *fs = NULL;
size_t bytes = sizeof(T);

if (IS_SIGNED(T))
    switch (bytes) {
        case 1: fs = PRId8;  break;
        case 2: fs = PRId16; break;
        case 4: fs = PRId32; break;
        case 8: fs = PRId64; break;
    }
else
    switch (bytes) {
        case 1: fs = PRIu8;  break;
        case 2: fs = PRIu16; break;
        case 4: fs = PRIu32; break;
        case 8: fs = PRIu64; break;
    }
```

With this method cast is not needed anymore, however format string has to be manually constructed before passing it to `printf` (i.e. no automatic string concatenation). Here is some working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define IS_SIGNED(T) (((T)-1) < 0)

/* using GCC extension: Statement Expr */
#define FMT_CREATE(T) ({                      \
    const char *fs = NULL;                    \
    size_t bytes = sizeof(ino_t);             \
                                              \
    if (IS_SIGNED(T))                         \
        switch (bytes) {                      \
            case 1: fs = "%" PRId8;  break;   \
            case 2: fs = "%" PRId16; break;   \
            case 4: fs = "%" PRId32; break;   \
            case 8: fs = "%" PRId64; break;   \
        }                                     \
    else                                      \
        switch (bytes) {                      \
            case 1: fs = "%" PRIu8;  break;   \
            case 2: fs = "%" PRIu16; break;   \
            case 4: fs = "%" PRIu32; break;   \
            case 8: fs = "%" PRIu64; break;   \
        }                                     \
    fs;                                       \
})

int main(void) {
    ino_t ino = 32;

    printf(FMT_CREATE(ino_t), ino); putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Note this requires some little trickery of [Statement Expr](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs), but there might be some other way (this is the "price" to be generic) as well.

#### EDIT:

Here is second version, that doesn't require specific compiler extension (don't worry I can't read it too) using function-like macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define IS_SIGNED(T) (((T)-1) < 0)
#define S(T) (sizeof(T))

#define FMT_CREATE(T)   \
    (IS_SIGNED(T)        \
        ? (S(T)==1?"%"PRId8:S(T)==2?"%"PRId16:S(T)==4?"%"PRId32:"%"PRId64) \
        : (S(T)==1?"%"PRIu8:S(T)==2?"%"PRIu16:S(T)==4?"%"PRIu32:"%"PRIu64))

int main(void)
{
    ino_t ino = 32;

    printf(FMT_CREATE(ino_t), ino);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Note that conditional operator has left assiociativity (thus it evalutes from left to right as intended).

Comment: I don't see how your `IS_SIGNED()` macro is determining if the variable is signed or not. I suppose you should use `IS_SIGNED(T) ((T) < 0 || ~(T) < 0)`

Comment: Wouldn't `#define IS_SIGNED(T) ((((T) & 0) - 1) < 0)` be better (or clearer)?

Comment: @FiddlingBits `T` is the name of a type here

Comment: This solution technically does the trick but it is a huge complication that will also cause performance to suffer because I either have to piece together formatting strings at runtime or call printf() multiple times in succession – both of which are things that are much more complicated than a simple cast.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I agree, it's not perfect in both performance and ease of use. Potentially there might be better solution in both aspects like internal built-in macro, that simply returns proper PRI* based on type, just as like `sizeof(T)` is compile-time operator, but it's outside of my current knowledge.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski I think the huge problem is that macros are expanded before any type-information is known. This also precludes any compile-time fiddling with string constants as string constants are concatenated by the compiler before type information is evaluated, too.