# Unix command "ls" in C

Tags: c, unix, ls, stat, opendir

After a long time to search a solution, I have to ask your precious help. I work on a program which implement "ls" unix command in C. I'd have only name of the file and his size. I looked that I've to use: "stat" and "dirent". I found a "solution" in Stackoverflow but didn't work perfectly for me.
So I can show the names of the file into the directory but not their size. 
When I use gcc, whether it shows: 0 octet (while it isn't empty) or "

> error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3
>   has type ‘__off_t’ [-Werror=format=]   printf("%s - %s", dp->d_name,
>   s->st_size);

"

My test code (not clean):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <poll.h>

struct stat statbuf;
struct dirent *dp;
struct stat *s;

int main ()
{
DIR *dirp;
dirp = opendir("/tmp/gestrep");

while((dp = readdir(dirp)) !=NULL)
{

    stat(dp->d_name, &statbuf);
    printf("%s - %s", dp->d_name, s->st_size);
}

}
```

In fact, I don't know how to solve the format type problem. I saw I could use ftell/fseek but I don't have the right to use FILE* functions.

Thank you for all solutions :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use printf to display off\_t, nlink\_t, size\_t and others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401526/use-printf-to-display-off-t-nlink-t-size-t-and-others)

Comment: Aren't you passing st_size (integral type) to a %s (null-terminated char string) format?

Comment: The first step in debugging is to read and understand the error. GCC is telling you exactly what and where the problem is.

Comment: When I change the %s to solve the format type problem with `int size = s->st_size; and printf("%s - %d", dp->dp_name, size);` It shows false informations about files

Comment: @user3723202 Instead of telling us that, you should show us a concrete example of a value that your program printed, and the value that was correct.  `s->st_size` is normally not an int, so your value might be truncated when you did `int size = s->st_size;` if the file size is large. There are answers and pointers to similar question (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401526/use-printf-to-display-off-t-nlink-t-size-t-and-others) that shows you how to print out an `off_t` type.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly cannot output the value of any integer type with a `%s` format code, and the error message you're getting from gcc should be perfectly clear.

Posix requires `off_t` to be an alias for some integer type, so a simple solution (with C11) would be to cast the value to an `intmax_t` (which is the widest integer type) and then use the `j` printf format size modifier:

```
printf("%s - %jd", dp->d_name, (intmax_t)s->st_size);
```

You'll need to make sure you include the appropriate header for `intmax_t` to be available:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```