# How to print size_t and ptrdiff_t using printf in ANSI C (C89)

Tags: c, printf, c89

I know this has been questioned many times on SO, but my problem is specific to ANSI C (C89).

In C99 there are the sub-specifiers `z` and `t`, which are not supported in ANSI C.

What about using the `p` specifier?

Comment: By the way, instead of down voting, you can share a link to the answer (if you can)

Comment: AFAIK ANSI autmatically adopts the ISO standard, so you should be able to use the same. In case you mean C89/90 ()which is unambiguous): there is no way. Note that C99 is not standard C; that would be C11.

Comment: Simply use %d. They are, asst the bottom of things, typedef to int

Comment: @levengli: Please refrain from stating such nonsense! `size_t` cannot be `int` and `ptrdiff_t` will not on systems where `int` is insufficient, like most 64 bit architectures and some 8/16 bit architectures

Comment: @levengli %lu is correcter, but not correct

Comment: @Olaf: Just because a standard has been superseded doesn't mean it isn't still a standard.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yeah, but every C standard explicitly invalidates its predecessor, so "*the C standard*" always refers to the latest one.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: The second release of the C standard (aka C99) has explicitly been **canceled**. Last time I check the meaning of this word it implied the second release is **not** standard. You might want to read the foreword of ISO9899:2011.

Comment: What is a `sub-specifier`?

Comment: @Olaf What is the point of arguing about this ? The OP explicitly asks about C89. The OP knows more about his environment than what you do, so if he asks about C89, simply provide an answer for that, or don't.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: I'd assume OP means the _length modifier_.

Comment: @nos: What do you mean? OP only mentions ANSI C which refers to the US institution. If he means C89(90 (they are bascially the same), he should add the appropriate tag; after all that's what tags are for. (maybe you check the edit-history and the timestamps before commenting)

Comment: @nos At the time of Olaf's comment, the question just said "ANSI C". OP edited the question to add "C89" afterwards.

Comment: "In 1990, the ANSI C standard (with formatting changes) was adopted by the International Organization for Standardization (ISO) as ISO/IEC 9899:1990, which is sometimes called C90. Therefore, the terms "C89" and "C90" refer to the same programming language." wikipedia

Comment: @BiteBytes Yes, and later ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (C99) was adopted as ANSI C, and then C11 was adopted as ANSI C.

Comment: @melpomene ok thank's.

Comment: @Olaf: A withdrawn standard doesn't stop being a standard, it stops being the current standard.  It seems that the question may have been edited within the edit window where revisions don't show, so if the question previously said "standard C" or something I can't speak to that.

Comment: You can always print it with `lu`, **with the value cast to `(unsigned long)`** - the actual value might be displayed modulo something big, but that's about the best you can get with such an obsolete standard.

Comment: The alternative is to write your own code to convert the value to decimal and write it on the given stream, it's quite easy, although of course it's not as convenient as a builtin `printf` specifier.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: That's why I use the same word the standard uses "canceled". I'm very confident it is not the same as "withdrawn". But feel free to provide an autoritative reference proving me wrong; I always like to learn something new. And the history shows very well the original version.

Comment: If there had been a way in pre-C99, it would not have had to be added to the standard, would it? C is not very famous for providing redundant features. Supporting @AnttiHaapala: Don't use such old versions; get a modern toolchain (gcc or clang are a good pick, including a lot of embedded systems) and write modern C. C90 has other problems and pitfalls. Not all are addressed by the current standard, but modern compilers will warn about a lot of them (which implies: **always enable all recommended warnings**).

Comment: @Olaf: It's true that the 2011 ISO C standard is the one currently recognized by ANSI, the American National Standards Institute. But you should be aware that practically *nobody* refers to C11 as "ANSI C". Even without the clarifying "(C89)", it was perfectly clear that the OP was asking about C89/C90. The OP's error (such as it was) was in referring to that language as "ANSI C". If you want to point that out, that's fine, but pretending that the OP really wanted to ask about a later standard is not helpful.

Comment: @KeithThompson: It is really funny how people only concentrate on the first part of my comment and completely ignore the much more relevant middle part which give the correct information.

Comment: @BiteBytes: Out of curiosity: what keeps you from using modern C (which started with C99)? Just blink if there is someone standing behind you with a gun.

Comment: @Olaf because it's the most portable version of C, and I wish I can restrict my programs to C89, and not using all the extra features that come with every compiler, witch make the program even less portable. The irony is that I started programming in 2005 using VB and C++ then I learned COM/OLE/AcitveX (yeah the evil from the old world), and I was fascinated by, then I learned C# and JAVA and Assembly Language after that, and I came up with the conclusion: "don't use what you don't need". So I started to clean the mess.

Comment: So to summarise: you stick with a 28 year old language instead of using an 18 year old or the already 6 year old current version. You willfully ignore the advances to enhance code quality. To be clear: this is not about "features", but to write good code! Sorry,but that makes me shiver.

Comment: @Olaf the problem is not with the modern language, and the extra features it has, the problem is  you're not going to find a compiler that support all those features in every platform you intend to target.

Comment: Wasn't part of the point of C99 to be more portable, e.g., with fixed-width integer types?

Comment: @DavidBowling: And to fixe such flaws like missing conversion type specifiers for standard types. Yes. That's exactly the point.

Comment: I wonder for which hosted environments you do **not** find a modern C compiler. Anyway, good luck for your job.

Comment: @Olaf Just in case, you never know, thank's for all.

Comment: Closely related to [How to use `printf()` to display `off_t`, `nlink_t`, `size_t` and other special types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401526)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`size_t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type.  `ptrdiff_t` is an implementation-defined signed integer type.

In C89/C90 (commonly, but strictly speaking incorrectly, referred to as "ANSI C"), there are no special format specifiers for these types. But the widest integer types are `long int` and `unsigned long int`, which of course do have their own format specifiers.

To print a `size_t` value, cast it to `unsigned long` and use `"%lu"`.

To print a `ptrdiff_t` value, cast it to `long` and use `"%ld"`.

Note that if your code is then compiled with a C99 or C11 compiler, it's possible that `size_t` and/or `ptrdiff_t` could be wider than `long`, and the code could fail. (As I recall the 64-bit Windows interface has 32-bit `long`, so that could be an issue in practice.)

In C99 and later, just use `%zu` for `size_t` and `%td` for `ptrdiff_t`. If you want your code to be *really* portable, consider using `#if` to test the value of `__STDC_VERSION__`.

You could also run into problems if you have a compiler that only *partially* conforms to C99 or C11.  You might have a compiler that doesn't fully support C99, but that does provide `long long`. But for the purpose of printing a `size_t` value, that's only going to be an issue if the value you're printing actually exceeds `ULONG_MAX`, which is at least 2<sup>32</sup>-1. For a `ptrdiff_t` value, converting to `long` is OK as long as it doesn't exceed `LONG_MAX`, which is at least 2<sup>31</sup>-1.

Finally, if you happen to know that the values you're printing aren't too big, you can get away with casting to `int` and using `%d`. I recommend casting to `unsigned long` or `long`, but `int` is OK for quick-and-dirty code.

> What about using the `p` specifier?

No, `%p` is only for pointers of type `void*`, and in any case the output format is implementation-defined (it's commonly hex, but I've seen other representations).

Comment: C89 says "There are four signed integer types, designated as signed char, short int, int, and long int". The problem with this provision is that literally no existing major implementation follows it to the letter. `size_t` may well be defined to be `long long unsigned int` or `__uint64` or some such. Who you gonna call?

Comment: @n.m.: A compiler that supports `long long unsigned int` and doesn't issue at least a warning message for any use of it is not a conforming C89/C90 compiler. `long long unsigned int` is a syntax error in C89/C90.

Comment: "is not a conforming C89/C90 compiler" this is a very correct observation, and also a very useless one. Here's your MSVC, go write some code. Not compliant? Who cares?

Comment: @n.m.: I've updated my answer to cover that possibility. Using the C89-conforming solution, it's only a problem if the value being printed exceeds `ULONG_MAX` or `LONG_MAX`.

Comment: I have tested gcc and clang in strict c90 mode, they both warn about `long long` but not about `uint64`, which is I suppose the expected behaviour. This is less relevant on Unixes where sizeof(long) is normally 8 in 64 bit mode, but I hear Windows builds like mingw use sizeof(long)==4. I wonder how is size_t defined there.

Comment: I would expect an undeclared identifier error for `int64`; I presume you meant `int64_t`. To refer to `int64_t` in C90 mode, you'd have to have `#include <stdint.h>`, which includes a non-standard header (non-standard headers are permitted, so there's nothing to warn about there). And if `long` is 64 bits, then the non-standard `<stdint.h.` can define `uint64_t` as `unsigned long`, so again there's no C90 conformance issue. I do see that I can `#include <stdint.h>` and refer to `uint64_t` with `gcc -std=c90 -pedantic -m32` (which forces 32-bit `long`), with no diagnostic. ...

Comment: ...  That *might* be a C90 conformance issue. n further investigation `<stdint.h>` has `typedef long long int int64_t;`, which should be a C90 syntax error, but the fact that it's a non-standard header might be relevant.

Comment: "A compiler that supports long long unsigned int and doesn't issue at least a warning message for any use of it is not a conforming C89/C90 compiler." There is no requirement to warn about wrong variadic arguments passed to `printf`, etc. Unless I missed something this never has been a requirement until, and including the (current) standard.

Comment: @Olaf: What I meant is that `long long int` is a syntax error in C89/C90. A conforming C89/C90 compiler must issue a diagnostic if it sees that token sequence. (gcc's failure to do so when it appears in the non-C90-standard `<stdint.h>` header seems questionable.)

Comment: As a sidenote: Support for the C99 modifiers is a matter of the standard library. Compilers like gcc don't provide the library, but rely on the existing one for the system. If you test at compile-time, there might be a problem when the code is run on a different environment.

Comment: Ok, that would be a possiblity. But as you know a compiler can provide more types than the standard ones and it is used exesively (actually `long long int` etc. were introduced to get some ground to incompatible wider types - I think I read something about the "battle" for the correct name), there is no guarantee it will be available on a different machine, too. However one sees it, it is patchwork. Exactly this wa the reason introducing the new specifiers (although one could argue the way of `inttypes.h`/`stdint.h` would have been the more portable)

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you guys, to ask again about the specifier `p`, I thought to my self, this one can print the address, which I assume is the longest integer in the machine (I guess), so why not using it to print `size_t`, where is the problem exactly? could `sizeof(size_t)` be greater than `sizeof(void*)`?

Comment: @BiteBytes: `%p` requires an argument of  type `void*`. Pointers are not integers, and they cannot safely be used interchangeably. Using `%p` with an argument of any type other than `void*` has undefined behavior. (It might also be valid to use `%p` with `char*`, `unsigned char*`, or `signed char*`, but I'd cast to `void*` anyway.)

Comment: You can cast `size_t` to `void*` and print that with `%p`. There is no guarantee in the standard that it is going to print the correct result, but in practice this should work on the vast majority of compilers (I cannot think of one which would not do the right thing).

Comment: @n.m.: I'd rather cast `size_t` to `unsigned long` and print with `%u`. That's guaranteed to print the correct result, as long as the value being printed doesn't exceed 2^32-1.

Comment: 3½ years later: Oops. I should have said `%lu` for `unsigned long`, not `%u`. Of course just use `%zu` for `size_t` if you can rely on having C99 or later.