# Trouble understanding fork() and process trees

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork

Based on the code below, I have been trying to make a process tree. At first I was thinking it would be similar to a binary tree that is symmetric, but no longer think so.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int status;
    pid_t i;

    i = fork();
    wait(&status);
    printf("a; i = %d\n", i);

    i = fork();
    wait(&status);
    printf("b; i = %d\n", i);

    i = fork();
    wait(&status);
    printf("c; i = %d\n", i);

    i = fork();
    wait(&status);
    printf("d; i = %d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, when running this code, there are 2x as many output as I have originally predicted. For example, `d` is printed out 16 times, but I figured it would only be printed out 8 times. Any deeper explanation would be helpful.

Comment: you got 2**(number of fork()) process that print your last line. That not clear what you ask.

Comment: yeah, I guess I was just confused as to how the tree would be organized. Like, would the initial parent node have four children branching from it or is it two children, and each children would create two more for each time `fork()` is called

Comment: As you should know `fork()` copy almost all from the parent this include output buffering, one should use `fflush(stdout)` before `fork()`, also there is no point to use wait in your child, so you should do `if (i != 0) { wait(&status); }` also you must check for error in your function call.

Comment: To help yourself understand, include PID and PPID in each `printf()` statement.  Also, capture and report the value (dead child PID) returned by `wait()` each time it is called (including the PID and PPID information too, of course); you can decide whether to report `status` or not, but initialize it to zero in case (for when) the `wait()` calls fail (because there is no child).  The children continue before the parent returns from the `wait()` calls, in general.

Answer (score 3):

To help yourself understand, include PID and PPID in each `printf()` statement.  Also, capture and report the value (dead child PID) returned by `wait()` each time it is called; you can decide whether to report `status` or not, but initialize it to zero in case (for when) the `wait()` calls fail because there is no child.  The children continue before the parent returns from the `wait()` calls, in general.

Or, better, write a logging function that can handle the details for you.
For example, consider this code:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void print_info(const char *tag, int corpse, int status, int child)
{
    int pid = getpid();
    int ppid = getppid();
    printf("PID %5d, PPID %5d: %s (corpse: %5d, status 0x%.4X), child %5d\n",
            pid, ppid, tag, corpse, status, child);
}

int main(void)
{
    int pid = getpid();
    int ppid = getppid();
    printf("Initial PID %5d, PPID %5d:\n", pid, ppid);

    int status = 0;
    int child = fork();
    int corpse = wait(&status);
    print_info("a", corpse, status, child);

    child = fork();
    corpse = wait(&status);
    print_info("b", corpse, status, child);

    child = fork();
    corpse = wait(&status);
    print_info("c", corpse, status, child);

    child = fork();
    corpse = wait(&status);
    print_info("d", corpse, status, child);

    return 0;
}
```

A sample run gives me:

```
Initial PID  7357, PPID 20754:
PID  7358, PPID  7357: a (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7359, PPID  7358: b (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7360, PPID  7359: c (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7361, PPID  7360: d (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7360, PPID  7359: d (corpse:  7361, status 0x0000), child  7361
PID  7359, PPID  7358: c (corpse:  7360, status 0x0000), child  7360
PID  7362, PPID  7359: d (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7359, PPID  7358: d (corpse:  7362, status 0x0000), child  7362
PID  7358, PPID  7357: b (corpse:  7359, status 0x0000), child  7359
PID  7363, PPID  7358: c (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7364, PPID  7363: d (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7363, PPID  7358: d (corpse:  7364, status 0x0000), child  7364
PID  7358, PPID  7357: c (corpse:  7363, status 0x0000), child  7363
PID  7365, PPID  7358: d (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7358, PPID  7357: d (corpse:  7365, status 0x0000), child  7365
PID  7357, PPID 20754: a (corpse:  7358, status 0x0000), child  7358
PID  7366, PPID  7357: b (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7367, PPID  7366: c (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7368, PPID  7367: d (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7367, PPID  7366: d (corpse:  7368, status 0x0000), child  7368
PID  7366, PPID  7357: c (corpse:  7367, status 0x0000), child  7367
PID  7369, PPID  7366: d (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7366, PPID  7357: d (corpse:  7369, status 0x0000), child  7369
PID  7357, PPID 20754: b (corpse:  7366, status 0x0000), child  7366
PID  7370, PPID  7357: c (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7371, PPID  7370: d (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7370, PPID  7357: d (corpse:  7371, status 0x0000), child  7371
PID  7357, PPID 20754: c (corpse:  7370, status 0x0000), child  7370
PID  7372, PPID  7357: d (corpse:    -1, status 0x0000), child     0
PID  7357, PPID 20754: d (corpse:  7372, status 0x0000), child  7372
```

You can chase through the data, seeing that there are 2<sup>4</sup> processes for the 4 `fork()` calls (after each call, there are 2 processes where there was 1 process before, so after one call there are 2 processes; after 2 calls, 4 processes; and so on), and that the child process exits before the parent gets to continue (so, in this example, PID 7357 is the last to print the `a` tag, and the `b` tag, and the `c` tag, and the `d` tag).

Any time you're having difficulty tracing the process tree, use a printing technique similar to this to help you understand what is going on better.

Comment: @Stargateur: thanks, but I carefully chose `int` as the type because it simplifies the code and works on extant POSIX systems - even ones like AIX with 8-digit PID values.

Comment: `pid_t` don't work on these system ? Or there are not C99 compliant maybe ? I think that unless the question refer a specific system, answer should use the most "up to date" code possible, still this is just a little detail as I said, your answer, your choice ;)

Comment: Yes, `pid_t` works; but it's unprintable. There's no format letter in [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) that is guaranteed correct for any of `pid_t`, `uid_t`, or `gid_t` (or [`id_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html)) defined by POSIX. So, to print such values, you have to cast to some known type with a known format specifier. I choose to use the known type `int` (which could in theory run foul of a system with a 16-bit `int` type and 32-bit `pid_t`, but it is an acceptable risk to me). YMMV, of course.

Comment: @Stargateur: See also [How to use `printf()` to display `off_t`, `nlink_t`, `size_t` and other special types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401526/how-to-use-printf-to-display-off-t-nlink-t-size-t-and-other-special-types)