# What primitive data type is time_t?

Tags: c, types, printf, time-t

I do not know the data type of `time_t`. Is it a float double or something else? Because if I want to display it I need the tag that corresponds with it for `printf`. I can handle the rest from there for displaying `time_t` but I need to know the data type that corresponds with it.

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471248/what-is-ultimately-a-time-t-typedef-to

Comment: For those who fall here searching how to printf a time_t, the same discussion applies to clock_t and has been done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083142/whats-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-clock-t).

Comment: @FirasAssaad That answer is for Linux.  this post is non-OS specific.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not completely portable.  It's usually integral, but it [can be](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/types.h.html) any "integer or real-floating type".

Answer (score 43):

It's platform-specific.  But you can cast it to a known type.

```
printf("%lld\n", (long long) time(NULL));
```

Comment: That assumes the platform supports (long long). It is precisely when it does not that you need to know that time_t is only 32-bit.

Comment: It also assumes that `long long` is large enough to hold the value. As far as the standard says `time_t` can be the number of yoctoseconds since the first Monty Python episode was aired (which will make it larger than 64 bits).

Comment: @skyking is not lying. You would need at least a 111-bit number to hold such a value (roughly 1.5e33). Until they put `long long long long` into the standard, you can prepare for the future by storing all your `time_t`s in a `uint64_t[2]`.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the function `difftime`. It returns the difference between two given `time_t` values, the output value is `double` (see [difftime documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/difftime.html)).

```
time_t actual_time;
double actual_time_sec;
actual_time = time(0);
actual_time_sec = difftime(actual_time,0); 
printf("%g",actual_time_sec);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always use something like mktime to create a known time (midnight, last night) and use difftime to get a double-precision time difference between the two.  For a platform-independant solution, unless you go digging into the details of your libraries, you're not going to do much better than that.  According to the C spec, the definition of time_t is implementation-defined (meaning that each implementation of the library can define it however they like, as long as library functions with use it behave according to the spec.)

That being said, the size of time_t on my linux machine is 8 bytes, which suggests a long int or a double.  So I did:

```
int main()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        printf ("%ld\n", time(NULL));
        printf ("%f\n", time(NULL));
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The time given by the %ld increased by one each step and the float printed 0.000 each time.  If you're hell-bent on using printf to display time_ts, your best bet is to try your own such experiment and see how it work out on your platform and with your compiler.

Comment: I know your comment is old, but you need to use `printf ("%f\n", (double) time(NULL));` because printf is a vararg function.