# Correctly recording the UNIX time in C (-Wall nightmare)

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What primitive data type is time_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792551/what-primitive-data-type-is-time-t)

Basically, all I want to do is produce the current UNIX time (result from time(NULL)) and print it to a file I have open.

I've tried code such as:

```
fprintf(f, "%i", time(NULL));
```

But I get these annoying compiler warnings:

```
src/database-createtbl.c:140: warning: int format, time_t arg (arg 3)
```

I'm trying to compile using -Wall - this really shouldn't be an issue but it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply cast to a known type:

```
printf("%ld", (long)time(NULL));
```

The type returned by `time` depends on the OS (it's aliased to `time_t`, but you don't know if this is `long` or `int` or something else), so you need to cast it to a known type before passing it to `printf`, in order for the format to match the argument type.

Comment: This is the most portable (to pre-C99), but using `long long` or `intmax_t` (or the unsigned versions thereof) and the corresponding C99 format specifiers may be safer, e.g. on a hypothetical post-Y2038 32-bit machine where `long` is 32 bits but `time_t` is 64 bits.