# Two dynamic parameters in printf

Tags: c

```
#ifndef UNICODE 
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[30];
    int counter=0;

    for(int i=0; i<22 ; i++)
    {       
        Sleep(1000);
        printf("%d %d\n",counter++,time(0));
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This version works fine, it outputs counter and the timestamps of the last 22 seconds. Unfortunately, when I did seemingly extraneous thing - replacing counter and time(0) , that is `printf("%d %d\n",time(0),counter++);` , function always printed 0 in place of counter! Any explanation of this strange fact?

Comment: What platform are you on, and what's the `sizeof(time_t)` there?

Comment: What is the actual return type of `time` on your platform? It could be `double` or `char[13]` for all we know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `time()` (on Windows at least) is a 64-bit integer. You must use a format other than `%d` to print it. Try `%lld`.

It worked when the time was last because you got the lower 32 bits, since Intel is a little-endian processor.

Answer (score 3):

`time()` returns type `time_t`, which is 64 bit on many platforms, while `"%d"` refers to `int` which is mostly 32bit.

Answer (score 2):

The `%d` format specifier means that `printf` is expecting an `int` type.  But `time()` returns a `time_t`; if that's bigger than an `int`, then more stuff will be put on the stack than `printf` is expecting, essentially offsetting the position of all subsequent arguments (so the upper bytes of the time value are interpreted as the second argument, in your case).

(To confirm, you should compare `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(time_t)`.)

For potential solutions, see the answers to e.g. this question: [What primitive data type is time_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792551/what-primitive-data-type-is-time-t).