# Suppress "value stored to during its initialization is never read"

Tags: clang, suppress-warnings

I'm using Xcode as my IDE on macOS for some [simple pure-C code](https://github.com/maurymarkowitz/RetroBASIC). The code uses stdlib's `rand`. [A former thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76367489/srand-rand-slowly-changing-starting-value/76367884#76367884) suggested calling `rand` twice near the start of `main` to better randomize it. So I added this code:

```
// seed the random with the provided number or randomize it based on the time
if (random_seed > -1)
  srand(random_seed);
else
  srand((unsigned int)time(NULL) | (getpid() << 8));

// now call rand to prime the pump
double pump = rand();
pump = rand();
```

This causes clang to complain that "Value stored to 'pump' during its initialization is never read", which is the entire point. I thought I could fix this by:

```
rand();
rand();
```

But then I get the complaint that "Return value of function rand() is not used". So I need to do something with the value to suppress the message(s).

Is there a way to fix this *in code*? It's been used on macOS, Win and Linuxen, so I'd like to avoid anything clang/Xcode/mac-ish or using the pre-processor. Is there some canonical method in C?

Comment: You already fudged the seed with the pid, the "pump" is pointless (given how rand is deterministic, I really don't see how that "pump" could ever help, unless it was called a random number of times - but you need a good random number to do that which you don't have).

Comment: It is not, click through to the link thread and you'll see why. I was getting the exact same sequences when running small programs that exited quickly. This code fixes this.