# How to get the min/max value of time_t (if type is unknown)

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, time-t

UBSAN complains about undefined behavior for when I run the [antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) utility:

```
runtime error: left shift of 1 by 63 places cannot be represented in type 'time_t' (aka 'long')
```

The error is triggered by the macros for `TIME_T_MIN` and `TIME_T_MAX` below.

```
#if !defined(TIME_T_MIN)
#define TIME_T_MIN      ((time_t)0 < (time_t)-1 ?\
                (time_t)0 :\
                (time_t)1 << (sizeof(time_t) * CHAR_BIT - 1))
#endif /* TIMER_T_MIN */

#if !defined(TIME_T_MAX)
#if defined(__TURBOC__) /* Turbo C chokes on the subtraction below */
#define TIME_T_MAX      (LONG_MAX)
#else   /* All others */
#define TIME_T_MAX      (~(time_t)0 - TIME_T_MIN)
#endif /* __TURBOC__ */
#endif /* TIME_T_MAX */
```

I contacted the antiword author and he suggests I find an alternative method to derive the min/max values for `time_t`.

What is a cross-platform method of calculating the min/max value of `time_t` if you are unsure what the underlying type is?

Comment: I don't think there is a universal method, as the standard is not specifying *anything* about the underlying type. There are plenty of duplicates by the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What primitive data type is time\_t?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792551/what-primitive-data-type-is-time-t)

Comment: OMG that's an old piece of software! I vaguely remember running it in Linux way back when. Also cool to see the RISC OS section state that Antiword "is 26/32 bit neutral". :) I think the best bet is to dive in and figure out *why* it wants to have the minimum value for a time, and perhaps refactor that.

Comment: Do you want the min/max _representable_ value for the data type of `time_t` or the min/max _valid_ value?  Example, `time_t` may be `long`, yet any value less than 0 _may_ not correspond to a valid time.  By _valid_ I mean returnable from `time()` or usable with `mktime()`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

C11's `_Generic` macro allows one to return min/max values of integral types:

```
#  define variable_min_value(_var)          \
    _Generic(_var,                  \
         char: CHAR_MIN,            \
         unsigned char: (unsigned char)0,   \
         signed char: SCHAR_MIN,        \
         signed short: SHRT_MIN,        \
         unsigned short: (unsigned short)0, \
         signed int: INT_MIN,           \
         unsigned int: 0u,          \
         signed long: LONG_MIN,         \
         unsigned long: 0ul,            \
         signed long long: LLONG_MIN,       \
         unsigned long long: 0ull)

#define TIME_T_MIN   (variable_min_value((time_t)0))
```

See [this library](https://github.com/ensc/ensc-lib/blob/master/type-utils.h) for other variants.

Comment: This is great. Note that the dupe-suggestion mentions that it might be floating-point, too.

Comment: Suggest extending this good answer to include `float, double, long double` as `time_t` is specified as a scalar - it could be FP.  Also a `default:` that is a compiler error may be useful.