# How to store the random seed generated from time(NULL) in a text file?

Tags: c, srand, random-seed, time-t

I am creating random numbers for my code and I am using the seeding method for the purpose of debugging. What I want to do is to store the return value of `time(NULL)` function which will be used by the `srand()` function. The value is to be stored in a log text file so that it can be used to analyze problems that occur in the code.

So how should I `printf` the exact value used as the seed in the `srand` function?

Comment: Unspecified. If it is POSIX, cast it to unsigned long long int. Note that `time_t` need not even be an *integer* in C, but POSIX requires this.

Comment: Store the result in the largest unsigned integer type supported by your system (usually a `uint64_t`) print it as such? That's the only way I could see this being in any way close to portable (considering that `time_t` *usually* is an integer type). The problem is that the actual type of `time_t` is implementation defined, it could be a floating point type, or even a structure. So the only *truly* portable way to print it, is as an actual textual date-time stamp.

Comment: OTOH, in any case you can convert the `time_t` value to `unsigned long long` *first*, and then use *that* value as the random seed

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm not entirely sure about that duplicate, because I smell an XY-Problem here, at least if I understand OPs intention correctly: to be able to reproduce a program run with "random" numbers in case something went wrong ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen what do you suggest then? rewrite the entire question so that it doesn't ask that :D I just remembered that `srand` eats unsigned int so perhaps just cast to `unsigned int` then.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I agree the way it is asked makes it look like a dupe :) But yes, that would be my suggestion as well. There's just no need to store a `time_t` here...

Comment: Ok reopened and edited.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Well thanks, I hope I didn't misunderstand the intention behind the question ;)

Comment: I think you have an XY problem. If you want to have reproducable pseudo random generation, just chose a "random" but fixed value for the initialization and keep it. There is no point at all that this would be the return value of `time()`.

Answer (score 4):

As already commented, `time_t` can be virtually anything, the description even changed with versions of the standard, so the only thing you know is that it is a number. I'd say the only *portable* way to write it to a file is to read the bytes of its representation and store them (*), e.g. in hex format, or directly as binary using `fwrite()`. For hex format, you could alias it with a `char *` and read the bytes by indexing from `0` to `sizeof(time_t) - 1`.

But then, you don't need the exact return value of `time()` for what you want to achieve, you only need the seed that was actually used! If you look at the `srand()` function, it takes an `unsigned int`. So just convert whatever `time(NULL)` returns to an `unsigned int` first and store that.

Note that the inner workings of the PRNG aren't specified in the standard either, so if you obtain a logfile from a user, there's no guarantee you can reproduce the same sequence of random numbers from it if he linked against a different C library.

---

(*) This of course is not portable at runtime between different implementations, as they will have different representations. I guess the question isn't about **that**, but for completeness, if you really want to store a time value, the way to go would be to store e.g. the components of a `struct tm` or use something like `strftime()`.

Comment: `srand` initialization is not portable between platforms because the `rand` algorithm is unspecified and thus could differ. If you need consistent PRN sequences between platforms, you need to use a clearly specified algorithm, including a specified seeding procedure which will use a clearly-defined bitwidth for the seed. As you say, it doesn't matter what the source of the seed is; only the seed itself.

Comment: @rici you did read my whole answer? I think I mentioned this issue as well :)

Comment: Looking carefully at your answer, no. I read and upvoted the original and then saw the last edit which I responded to. I missed the intermediate edit. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The function [time()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) returns `time_t` type which [can be any integer or real-floating type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2792556/1110642).

[But you can cast it to a known type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2792619/1110642):

```
printf("%lld\n", (long long) time(NULL));
```

If you just want to store the **binary** `time_t` value in order to read it back later you could do:

Write:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
/* ... open file handle */
fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, file);
```

Read:

```
time_t t = 0;
/* ... open file handle */
fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, file);
```

When doing this you have to make sure that wrting and reading is done by the same binary (or different binaries but same compiler).

Comment: But will the exact value (long long) time(NULL) be used in the srand function or will another value go in srand? Because I need to store the exact value of time(NULL) that will be used in srand(time(NULL))?

Comment: See your own reference where a comment says "That assumes the platform supports (long long)." and another solution proposes `difftime` which is double.