# Are there types bigger than long long int in C++?

Tags: c++, types

Are there types bigger than long long int in C++?

My compiler is g++.

Comment: What types are you talking about? Integer types or any types? What's "bigger" in this case: range or size? In any case, type `int[100]` is most likely a lot bigger than `long long`, but I don't think this is what you are asking about. Clarify your question. At this time it makes little sense.

Comment: you could try long long long (I'm just kidding) I believe long long is the biggest at 64 bits on all architectures

Comment: You might check out this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), which links to a number of libraries that can handle larger-than-long-long storage.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos: With at least 64 bits (could be bigger). @AndreyT: Not officially, but it is a nearly ubiquitous extension that we also expect to see in the next version of the standard (to bring us into line with C).

Comment: The thing is that sizeof(long long) has a loose definition being sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long) so on certain machines they are actually the same size 0_0 odd aint it

Comment: `__m128` in my compiler, not standard of course.

Comment: where do I click when a comment is technically correct but excessively nitpicky...  @AndreyT seriously, you didn't understand what he meant?

Comment: @Spike0xff: No, I didn't. While the `int[100]` was obviously an intentional exaggeration (as I said right away), there's still no way to figure out whether, say, `double` can qualify as "bigger" type for OP's purposes. Is it? I don't know. It has "wider" absolute range, but it comes with trade-offs, since it has the same number of bytes (assuming both are 64 bit). So, is it "bigger" or not? If this is perfectly clear to you, then please explain it to me.

Comment: **unsigned long long**

Answer (score 23):

There is a gcc [extension for 128 bit integers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html).

Comment: Note: `intmax_t` does not consider it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265462/why-in-g-stdintmax-t-is-not-a-int128-t

Answer (score 12):

No, but you can use libraries like [GMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library) to handle bigger numbers.

Answer (score 11):

Depending on what your need is, you could create your own struct to handle the data type:

```
#include <cstdint>

struct uint256_t
{
    std::uint64_t bits[4];
};

uint256_t x;
```

Answer (score 8):

`__int128`
`__uint128`

​​​​​ ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: __int128 is not enabled on Microsoft Visual

Comment: @BrendanWebster Can you enable it?

Answer (score 7):

**Standards**

Extended integer types are explicitly allowed by the C and C++ standards.

**C++11**

[C++11 N3337 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 3.9.1 "Fundamental types" paragraph 3 says:

> There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long long int”. In this list, each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list. There may also be implementation-defined extended signed integer types. The standard and extended signed integer types are collectively called signed integer types. Plain ints have the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment  the other signed integer types are provided to meet special needs.

You should also consider `intmax_t`, which 18.4.1 "Header  synopsis" paragraph 2 says:

> The header defines all functions, types, and macros the same as 7.18 in the C standard.

**C99**

[C99 N1256 draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) explicitly allows them at 6.2.5 "Types" paragraph 4:

> There are five standard signed integer types, designated as signed char, short int, int, long int, and long long int. (These and other types may be
>   designated in several additional ways, as described in 6.7.2.) There may also be implementation-defined extended signed integer types.28) The standard and extended signed integer types are collectively called signed integer types.29)

and 7.18.1.5 "Greatest-width integer types" paragraph 1 says:

> The following type designates a signed integer type capable of representing any value of any signed integer type:
>
> intmax_t

Comment: intmax_t is basically a long long

Answer (score 6):

Summarizing...

If you need to store exact integer values that won't fit in 'long long', gcc offers the type [__int128](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html). *This is a gcc extension*, not part of standard C++ (as of this writing).

If you need to work with even bigger exact integer values, you probably need an [arbitrary-precision arithmetic package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigint), such as [GMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library).  If your need is very limited you could roll your own extended precision code, but that can quickly become more complicated (and less efficient and reliable) than using an existing library.

If you need to store larger numbers but don't need to store the larger values exactly, you can use **float** or **double**: These can represent numbers of much larger magnitude, but with less [precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_precision).

And of course, if you just want to take up more memory, declare an array ;-)

Comment: Could one possibility be to use `streampos`, depending on the size needed?

Comment: @jorgen streampos is probably not a help in general, as C++ 11 says "It is a typdef of one the fundamental signed integral types..."

Answer (score 3):

If you know your number is always going to be positive, you can extend the scope of an `int` by labeling it as `unsigned`

`int myNum;           // Range is from –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`

`unsigned int myNum;  // Range is from 0 to 4,294,967,295`

Answer (score 1):

you can check out BigInt class...
http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/

(There are many other BigInts out there...)

Answer (score 1):

In g++, there is a `__int128` in `cstdint` header.

`__int128` is 128 bit data type. Range is from -2^128 to 2^128-1. You can use `__int128` with

```
#include <cstdint>

int main(){
    __int128 bignumber;
}
```

Comment: For Visual Studio users; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39016672/15543476).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>  
using namespace boost::multiprecision;
```

to work with data type bigger than long long int and the data type is `cpp_int` [Ref](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-huge-number-check-power-two/)