# 128-bit integer in visual studio 6

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 64-bit, int128

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable __int128 on Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759592/how-to-enable-int128-on-visual-studio)

In Visual Studio 6, I've `__int32` and `__int64` integer data types but I can't have `__int128` although I'm working on 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 2):

It's [not defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z.aspx), and won't be implemented, according to [this question on MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/529171/implement-128-bit-type)

Comment: and even if it was going to be implemented, it certainly wouldn't be implemented in a 13 year old compiler

Comment: I read in a header file named "limits" not "limits.h" that if "integerbits" more than or equal 128 a specific "#define constant" is defined, anyway, it seems that i don't have my "integerbits"like this, but what is the "integerbits" ?