# typedef for a signed type that can contain a size_t?

Tags: c++, c, size-t

Is there a standard (or MSVC proprietary) typedef for a signed type that can contain the full range of `size_t` values?  I.e. on a 64-bit system, it would be a 128-bit signed integer.

Comment: Oops typo in title.  I was asking about a signed type.

Comment: On the off chance that the reason you want a signed type is to overload/escape it with special meaning, you could consider the `boost::optional<>` wrapper.

Comment: Why 128 bits? 65 would be sufficient.

Comment: OK you're right, I'm just assuming that sizes go up in powers of 2 :)

Comment: About size_t and ptrdiff_t - http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0050/

Comment: @japreiss  Note: I've work with systems with int24 and int48. (Didn't use them much as they are _weird_.) Power of 2 is certainly the most common.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use 128-bit integer in MSVC++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775248/can-i-use-128-bit-integer-in-msvc)

Comment: [How to enable __int128 on Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6759592/995714)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's not possible in general to define such a type. It's perfectly legal for an implementation to make `size_t` the largest supported unsigned type, which would (almost certainly) mean that no signed type can hold all its values.

`ptrdiff_t` is not necessarily wide enough. It's the result of subtracting two pointers, but there's nothing that says a pointer subtraction cannot overflow. See section 5.7 of the C++ standard:

> When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted,
> the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array
> elements. The type of the result is an implementation-defined signed
> integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as
> **`std::ptrdiff_t`** in the **`<cstddef>`** header (18.2). As with any other
> arithmetic overflow, if the result does not fit in the space provided,
> the behavior is undefined.

The largest signed type is `intmax_t`, defined in `<stdint.h>` or `<cstdint>`. That's a C99 feature, and C++11 was the first C++ standard to incorporate the C99 standard library, so your compiler might not support it (and MSVC most likely doesn't). (*9 years later: that's no longer much of an issue.*) If there's a signed type wide enough to hold all possible values of type `size_t`, then `intmax_t` is (though there *might* be a narrower signed type that also qualifies).

You can also use `long long`, which is a signed type guaranteed to be at least 64 bits (and most likely the same as `intmax_t`). Even if it's not wide enough to hold all possible values of type `size_t`, it will almost certainly hold all *relevant* values of type `size_t` -- unless your implementation actually supports objects bigger than 8 exabytes (that's 8192 petabytes, or 8388608 terabytes).

(Note, I'm using the binary definitions of "exa-", "peta-", and "tera-", which are of questionable validity.)

Comment: *"and MSVC most likely doesn't"* - As a side note the new integer types were indeed one of the few C++11 features that the *MSVC* standard library had since *2010*.

Comment: Also if you're not sure what sizes you're going to get on a given platform then add a:`static_assert(sizeof(intmax_t) > sizeof(size_t), "Can't get a signed type guaranteed to hold a size_t");` so the compiler will warn you if you're about to potentially get into trouble.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a standard type that can contain the maximum value of the system, maybe the `<cstdint>` (since C++11) could help.

There's a typedef in that header that holds the maximum width integer type, the type is `intmax_t`. The `intmax_t` for signed integers, and the `uintmax_t` for the unsigned ones are the largest integer fully supported by the architecture.

So, let's suppose you're in a 64bit architecture, the following instruction:

```
std::cout << "intmax_t is same int64_t? "
          << (std::is_same<intmax_t, int64_t>::value ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Will output:

> intmax_t is same int64_t? Yes

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/p0gDYL).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not the signed version of size_t. intmax_t  is 8-bytes on x64 (same as size_t), but also 8-bytes on 32-bit whereas size_t is 4 bytes in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you need this type for some kind of pointer arithmetic. It is very unlikely that you need anything else than `std::ptrdiff_t`. The only case where this will play a role on a modern machine is when you are in 32-bit mode and you are working on a data set with more than 2^31 bytes. (This won't even be possible on Windows without special work.) You won't be able to use two arrays of that size at the same time. In this case you should probably work in 64-bit mode anyways.

In 64-bit mode it will most likely not be a problem for the next 40 years or so with the current speed of memory development. And when it becomes a problem, then compile your code in 128-bit mode and it will continue to run. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a signed type that can hold every value of `std::size_t` as *positive values*, I don't know of a way. Assuming you have the same number of bits, it takes one bit of information to store sign, so the new maximum is half the old. On the other hand, the upper half of values that used that bit are just wrapped into the negatives, so you can always cast back.

Really, what you probably need is to separate high unsigned / negative signed values from the others wherever you would cast them. If unsigned `0 <= x < M/2 <= y <= M` maps to `0 <= (x, y & (M/2)) < M/2`, then every value is accounted for, but won't wrap as x or y in either direction. It's the same if signed `-M/2 <= y < 0 <= x < M/2` maps to `0 <= (x, y+M/2) < M`.

This way you know when `x < 0` or `y > M/2` that it's out of range to convert back, but in the meantime you can do comparisons like unsigned `y(M) < y(M)+1` or signed `x(0) > x(0)-1` that normally fail after wrapping, like `0 < -1 = M`, `M > M+1 = 0`, etc.

For the record, I believe the corresponding signed type to `std::size_t` is best computed, `std::make_signed_t<std::size_t>`. Currently it is most likely `long long` from `unsigned long long`, but I don't know how universal that is or if it'll ever change. I recommend using `std::numeric_limits<T>` from there to check the min/max when you get it anyway.

Comment: Upvote for `std::make_signed_t<std::size_t>`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm beginning to doubt myself. Any idea if conversion back from a computed signed type is guaranteed, or if it could hypothetically be larger?  Lack of direct support for this concept and use of independently defined `ptrdiff_t`, etc. makes me wonder if we're asking the right questions. Looking at `std::ssize`, I see that they take the `common_type` of `ptrdiff_t` and `make_signed_t<decltype(c.size())>`, so the larger of the two. This makes me think there's at least more to consider.

Comment: I asked for clarification on `std::ssize` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71832666/in-stdssize-why-return-the-common-type-of-decltypec-size-and-ptrdiff-t?noredirect=1#comment126938502_71832666). In any case, if you're sure you want exactly the same size data type, so the upper half of `std::size_t` becomes negative, `std::make_signed_t<std::size_t>` is what you want.

Comment: From cppreference.com on [`std::make_signed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_signed): _"If T is ... (list of types that does **not** include `std::size_t`) ... 

Otherwise, the behavior is undefined. (until C++20)
Otherwise, the program is ill-formed. (since C++20)"_ In other words, `std::make_signed` can't be used for `std::size_t`.