# difference of two string size

Tags: c++, c++11

for example

```
string s1 = "";
string s2 = "a";
```

The print out of

```
cout << s1.size() - s2.size() << endl;
```

is 18446744073709551615?

What's happening here?

Comment: If `size` is returning a unsigned value, `0 - 1` would cause an underflow. I can't remember what type it returns off the top of my head though.

Comment: 3 answers explaining the problem, none of them showed how to fix it. :(

Comment: @Barmar - fixing is simple - just comment out the `cout` line.

Comment: @Barmar convert to int

Comment: @JerryXue I know that. But when I made my comment, none of the answers showed that.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::string::size`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) returns a [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) - while the actual type used for this is implementation defined, it's guaranteed to be **unsigned**:

> std::size_t is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator

As a result, subtracting two `std::size_t`'s (`0 - 1`, in this case) can result in integer underflow, causing the resulting value to wrap-around from a "negative" value to a very large positive value.

---

The value you got, `18446744073709551615`, is the same as `2^64 - 1` (which is `-1` after underflow on a 64-bit integer), which is in accordance with the above.

---

To "fix" this (ie. to get `-1` instead of the underflowed value), you'll need to cast your values to a signed type before doing the subtraction. However as you can see from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352403/typedef-for-a-signed-type-that-can-contain-a-size-t), there's no signed type that's guaranteed to be large enough. We can make do with `long long`:

```
long long diff = static_cast<long long>(s1.size()) - static_cast<long long>(s2.size());
```

Comment: Would you like to show how he can fix his code to get the answer he's looking for?

Comment: @Barmar Updated, although there's a bit of an implementation hiccup.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of [`std::string::size` is `size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size). `size_t` is an [unsigned integer type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) and as such, an operation of `size_t(0) - size_t(1)` will result in integer underflow.

If you really need to do this operation, then you can cast the result of `size` to a signed integer type to do the calculation:

```
cout << static_cast<long int>(s1.size()) - static_cast<long int>(s2.size()) << endl;
```

Comment: Would you like to show how he can fix his code to get the answer he's looking for?

Answer (score 0):

`string::size` returns a `size_t` - i.e. `size_t` is an unsigned type. So it can store only positive numbers.

So -1 is converted to an unsigned number.

As per the standard, the negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its value from 2<sup>n</sup>, where `n` is the number of bits in the promoted operand.

On your system, `size_t` is a 64 bit unsigned type, so n is 64. 
So what's printed is

2<sup>64</sup> - 1 = 18446744073709551615

Comment: Would you like to show how he can fix his code to get the answer he's looking for?