# cout printing a large number in cpp

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int countChars(string s1, string s2) {

  int a = 0, result = 0, i = 0;
  for(i =0; i<s1.size(); i++) {
    if(a == s2.size()) {
      break;
    }
    if(s1.at(i) == s2.at(a)) {
      a++;
    } else {
      result++;
    }
  }

  cout << (s2.size() - a - 1) << "\n";
  result += (s1.size()-i + s2.size()-a-1);

  return result;
}

int main() {
  cout << countChars("madame", "madam");
}
```

The above code is printing

18446744073709551615

0

I am not able to understand the reason behind the output of the problem. Can anyone explain why is `cout << (s2.size() - a - 1) << "\n";` printing `18446744073709551615`?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218098/difference-of-two-string-size

Comment: Use a debugger to look at the values of `s2.size()` and `a`. If you don't have a debugger, you can just print it: `cout << s2.size() << "\n"; cout << a << "\n";`

Comment: @davidbak That is not the correct base 2 representation of the number given; it is 2^64 - 1

Comment: To duplicate, you can just execute std::cout << size_t(-1);

Comment: @MM - well darn, I used the simplest Windows app, calc, wrong ....

Answer (score 0):

This is because `s2.size()` is of type `size_t`, which is a unsigned type, therefore the whole expression `(s2.size() - a - 1)` will be interpreted unsigned ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770258/how-do-promotion-rules-work-when-the-signedness-on-either-side-of-a-binary-opera)). However the actual value of this expression can be negative, assigning a negative value into an unsigned type results in a large positive value ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221409/is-unsigned-integer-subtraction-defined-behavior)).

A solution is to convert the value to a signed type:

```
cout << static_cast<int>(s2.size() - a - 1);
```

This should yield expected results.