# In std::ssize, why return the common_type of decltype(c.size()) and ptrdiff_t?

Tags: c++, types, c++17, size, signed

I wanted a signed type corresponding to `std::size` (ideally computed from it rather than relying on another definition that could be independent.) Naturally I thought to use `std::make_signed_t<std::size_t>`.

However, when I looked at `std::ssize`, I noticed the return type was `std::common_type_t` of `std::ptrdiff_t` and `decltype(c.size())`. Now `c.size()` should be unsigned, but in either case, it should become signed because `std::ptrdiff_t` is. All that's left is the size; that should be the larger of the two types.

What I don't get is why you would use a large type like `std::ptrdiff_t` as if you wanted the largest signed type. If it really were the largest, there would be no point to the `std::common_type_t`. Instead, assuming `std::common_type_t` doesn't always return `std::ptrdiff_t`, that means `decltype(c.size())` is a different size, and effectively `std::ptrdiff_t` is used for a minimum-size signed type. And if that's the case, shouldn't the smallest signed type be used instead? Or, why wouldn't the signed type corresponding to `decltype(c.size())` be used directly? What could be the intent behind that definition?

Comment: _"shouldn't the smallest signed type be used instead?"_  That could be problematic.  If my container was guaranteed to have a size in the range [0,255] then a `std::uint8_t` would be a fine return type for `size()`.  A `std::int8_t` would not be appropriate for `std::ssize` though.

Comment: It could be problematic, but isn't that your expectation when getting `std::ssize(c)`? Or do you expect a (signed) type larger than `decltype(c.size())`? I thought it was assumed that the size would be the same and that large values would become negative.

Comment: You can see some reasoning in the paper which introduced `std::ssize`, although I am not entirely convinced by it either: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1227r2.html The proposal tries to avoid large sizes becoming negative.

Comment: Because [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) must return a signed type, we must assume that the size of any container can correctly fit in some signed type.  That is the job `std::ptrdiff_t` is assuming.

Comment: I thought that meant the size of containers was limited, not that `std::size_t` reflected that. I thought the maximum of `std::ptrdiff_t` was the real limiting factor in pointer offset and that `std::size_t` might have an extra bit compared to the largest pointer difference.