# Is there an actual 8-bit integer data type in C++

Tags: c++, integer

In c++, specifically the cstdint header file, there are types for 8-bit integers which turn out to be of the char data type with a typedef. Could anyone suggest an actual 8-bit integer type?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: As I understand it, `int8_t` is guaranteed to be an 8-bit integer, if it is defined at all.  The fact that your implementation typedef's it as `char` (or maybe `signed char`) implies that your implementation's `char` is in fact 8 bits.  Note that `char` and its relatives are always integer types in C and C++; this differs from some other languages that don't treat characters as arithmetic types.

Comment: In the more common implementations, `char` is 8 bits. If it isn't 8 bits, there won't be a `std::int8_t`.

Comment: Think of it like this: `char` is string character type, and should not be used for anything else. `unsigned char` and `signed char` are used as arithmetic types and are not useful for string characters.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, you are right. `int8_t` and `uint8_t` are `typedef` to `char` on platforms where 1 byte is 8 bits. On platforms where it is not, appropriate definition will be given.

Following answer is based on assumption that char is `8 bits`

`char` holds 1 byte, which may be `signed` or `unsigned` based on implementation.

So `int8_t` is `signed char` and `uint8_t` is `unsigned char`, but this will be safe to use int8_t/uint8_t as actual 8-bit integer without relying too much on the implementation.

For a implementer's point of view, `typedef`fing where char is 8 bits makes sense.

Having seen all this, **It is safe to use `int8_t` or `uint8_t` as real 8 bit integer.**

Comment: Note that `int8_t` may not be a typedef to `char` on platforms in which `char` is less than 8 bits.

Comment: My belief is that `char` is 1 byte. Is it not? May be  I need to reconfirm myself :) now

Comment: `char` is 1 byte indeed, but 1 byte is not always 8 bits, see e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char). Although my belief is that `int8_t` is not defined for platforms in which a byte is not 8 bits.

Comment: Thanks, Updating accordingly. Learn something new today. That's why SO is great.

Comment: No, they are not `typedef` to `char`.  First, the `char` type is compiler dependent and can be `unsigned`, `signed` or `char`.  A `int8_t` is a `signed` quantity and `uint8_t` is an unsigned quantity.  They cannot be mapped to the same type.  The only guarantee is that `int8_t` is a signed integer of 8-bits and `uint8_t` is an **unsigned** integer that is 8-bits wide.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have mentioned that in the answer. May be my wording is not clear enough. Can you Add the appropriate one. Not a native speaker. I think char be either `signed` or `unsigned`, but not `char`.

Comment: @vsoftco `char` has to be a minimum of 8 bits.  It is even called out at the end of the link you provided.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry, cannot find where. Can you point out the quote/standard? There is something about *18.2.2*, but didn't find anything in the C++ standard about `char` there.

Comment: I just want to throw in that the POSIX specification clearly demands that `CHAR_BIT == 8`, so for any evironment that is POSIX compliant, or has a legacy that was so, then `char` will be 8 bits. So for 99% of what typical (as in: not embedded firmware, DSP and such) programs are going to run in an environment where char is 8 bits.

Comment: "Appropriate definition will be given" should read "the types will not exist"

Comment: @vsoftco — **[intro.memory]** /1: _A byte is at least large enough to contain [...] **eight-bit** code units_

Comment: @NathanOliver I think there is something in the C standard *5.2.4.2.1*, which C++ 18.2.2 quotes.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Perfect, thanks! Frankly I didn't know this.

Comment: @vsoftco look up the specification for limits.h, it will say that `UCHAR_MAX` must be at least `255` (from which we can deduce that it must be at least 8 bits)

Comment: @M.M I also found [*5.2.4.2.1* (pg. 22)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) which mandates `CHAR_BIT` (*number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (**byte**)*) to be at least 8. This part of the C standard is being invoked by the C++ standard in *18.2.2*.

Comment: The int8_t and uint8_t types for gcc version 4.9.2, adsurdly, store numbers as char type and are integers only when either is in a mathematical expression

Comment: @tej-kweku: I'm pretty sure that's exactly what `int8_t` and `uint8_t` are for, as specified by the C++ spec.

Comment: It is safe to use them indeed, but not if you want to print them as integers, they will be printed as `char`s, with all their usual rules. If you want to print them as integers cast them to an integer type when you do the printing.

Answer (score 0):

There are `__int8`, `__int16`, `__int32`, `__int64` default data type (this also
applied for C programming language), without using the `<cstdint>` header and there aren't `__int128` for Microsoft-specific (lot of answers is at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759592/how-to-enable-int128-on-visual-studio), and even intrinsic function `__shiftleft128`, `__shiftright128` use two `__int64` for example).

`int8_t` is `char` are also applied for unsigned types, for example, `uint8_t` are `unsigned char`.

Comment: All of `__int...` are compiler-specific. Which compilers did you test on?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The list is MSVC, Watcom and MinGW. But __int128 seems to be not exist but shown when I am writing code in Visual Studio.

Comment: Doesn't work [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KMhjnG3Wq) (I think they run Linux). Probably a Windows-specific extension.

Comment: And it doesn't work [here](https://godbolt.org/z/no6h9WK74)