# Cannot calculate factorials bigger than 20! ! How to do so?

Tags: c, gcc, factorial

I am using unsigned long long integer format in order to calculate big factorials. However my code fails at some point can you have a look at it? Actually it is part of a larger code for Taylor expansion of exponential function, but that part is irrelevant at this point. I will appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//We need to write a factorial function beforehand, since we
//have factorial in the denominators.
//Remembering that factorials are defined for integers; it is
//possible to define factorials of non-integer numbers using
//Gamma Function but we will omit that.
//We first declare the factorial function as follows:
unsigned long long factorial (int);
//Long long integer format only allows numbers in the order of 10^18 so 
//we shall use the sign bit in order to increase our range.
//Now we define it,
unsigned long long
factorial(int n)
{
//Here s is the free parameter which is increased by one in each step and
//pro is the initial product and by setting pro to be 0 we also cover the
//case of zero factorial.
    int s = 1;
    unsigned long long pro = 1;
    if (n < 0)
        printf("Factorial is not defined for a negative number \n");
    else {
    while (n >= s) { 
    printf("%d \n", s);
    pro *= s;
    s++;
    printf("%llu \n", pro);
    }
    return pro;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int x[12] = { 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 100, -1, -5, -10, -20, -50, -100};
//Here an array named "calc" is defined to store 
//the values of x.
unsigned long long  k = factorial(25);
printf("%llu \n", k);

//int k;
////The upper index controls the accuracy of the Taylor Series, so
////it is suitable to make it an adjustable parameter. 
//int p = 500;
//for ( k = 0; k < p; k++);

}
```

Comment: 20! is becoming a thing now. :) Since it's right at the limit of overflowing a 64-bit integer.

Comment: Read [Which data type or data structure to choose to calculate factorial of 100?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205587/which-data-type-or-data-structure-to-choose-to-calculate-factorial-of-100/15205645#15205645)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The limit on an unsigned long long is 18446744073709551615, or about 1.8e+19.  20! is about 2.4e+18, so within range, however 21! is about 5.1e+19, exceeding the maximum size of an unsigned long long.

You may find this helpful: [Are there types bigger than long long int in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381882/types-bigger-than-long-long-in-c)

Answer (score 7):

You're overflowing your integer type. It's likely that `unsigned long long` is 64 bits long for you.

- 20! is `0x21c3_677c_82b4_0000` which fits.
- 21! is `0x2_c507_7d36_b8c4_0000` which does not fit.

You can look into libraries like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) which enable arbitrarily large integers.

---

To extend the GMP comment. Here's some code that will calculate the factorial using GMP:

```
void factorial(unsigned long long n, mpz_t result) {
    mpz_set_ui(result, 1);

    while (n > 1) {
        mpz_mul_ui(result, result, n);
        n = n-1;
    }
}

int main() {
    mpz_t fact;
    mpz_init(fact);

    factorial(100, fact);

    char *as_str = mpz_get_str(NULL, 16, fact);
    printf("%s\n", as_str);

    mpz_clear(fact);
    free(as_str);
}
```

This will calculate `factorial(100)`, and results in:

```
0x1b30964ec395dc24069528d54bbda40d16e966ef9a70eb21b5b2943a321cdf10391745570cca9420c6ecb3b72ed2ee8b02ea2735c61a000000000000000000000000
```

---

And just for fun, here's the C++ version. Constructors, destructors and operator overloading tend to make the C++ version of these things look a bit cleaner. The result is the same as before.

```
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    mpz_class fact = 1;

    for (int i=2; i<=100; ++i)
        fact *= i;

    std::cout << "0x" << fact.get_str(16) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Specifically, 21! would require 66 bits.

Comment: @Vesnog: Yes. mpz_get_str's second argument is the base of the represented number. You can pass anything from 2 to 16 in there.

Answer (score 5):

Range of `unsigned long long` is usually **0** to **2^64 - 1** (`18,446,744,073,709,551,615`). 21! goes out of this range.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem I guess so that is the universal limit, kind of?

Comment: Yes. It is C99 standard defined.

Comment: @haccks Just note for clarity: 0 to 2^64 - 1 is the _minimum_ range for `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @chux; Then what is the maximum range?

Comment: @haccks There is no C specification for a _maximum_ range.  A platform may use a 16-byte `unsigned long long` and have a range 0 to 2^128 - 1.  If one wants with certainty a 64-bit number, C provides the uint64_t type.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed:

```
2^64 = 18446744073709551616
21!  = 51090942171709440000
20!  =  2432902008176640000
```

By the way, to calculate the result of a series (e.g., Taylor) you should not calculate each term separately; this will definitely bring you problems such as this one.  Instead, try to calculate each term by reusing the previous one.

For example, the Taylor series for `cos` requires the summation of terms like:

```
(-1)^i * (x^(2*i)) / (2i)!
```

It is easy to see that each term can be calculated easily from the previous one:

```
newterm = - oldterm * x^2 / ((2i+1)*(2i+2))
```

So, I believe that you don't need to calculate large factorials, for what you're trying to do.  On the other hand, if you need to, you'll have to use  a library for big numbers, such as [`gmp`](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: I think that is the exact barrier how can I surpass it?

Comment: On the other hand, one must be careful about the numerical stability of the algorithm when chaining all those FP calculations.

Answer (score 2):

factorial(25) should give the result 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 which is larger than the range of unsigned long long [Data Type Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

A long long is only so big, and thus can only represent numbers so big.  If you need an exact representation of bigger integers, you'll need to use something else (some 3-rd party library or some datatype you make yourself); if you don't need it to be exact, then you could use double's instead.

Comment: I infer from your comment that since we do not have something called long long long integer calculating 21! is impossible without resorting to external libraries of how to do so I have no idea of. Am I right? By the way how can you make datatypes ??

Comment: I don't know of any compiler that supports long long long.  As for a library, you could try this: http://gmplib.org

Answer (score 0):

A simple algorithm that i wrote.  but it's in Java..
You can calculate factorial of 1000 in about 15 minutes.

This algorithm works with the basic formula that we learnt at primary school.

```
/* FOR BEST RESULT DON'T CHANGE THE CODE UNTIL YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING */
    public String factorial(int number){
        if(number == 0) return "1";
        String result = "1";
        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
            result = *longNumberMultiplyingAlgorithm*(result, "" + (i + 1));
        }
        return result;  
    }

    public String longNumberMultiplyingAlgorithm(String number1, String number2){
            int maxLength = Math.max(number1.length(), number2.length());
            int a = 0;
            String[] numbers = new String[maxLength];

            if(number2.length() > number1.length()){
                String t = number1;
                number1 = number2;
                number2 = t;
            }       

            for(int i = 0; i < number1.length(); i++){
                numbers[i] = "";
                a = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < number2.length(); j++){
                    int result = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number1.charAt(number1.length() - i - 1))) * Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number2.charAt(number2.length() - j - 1)));
                    if(result + a < 10){
                        numbers[i] = (result + a) + "" + numbers[i];
                        a = 0;
                    }else{
                        result += a;
                        a = (int)((result + 0.0) / 10);
                        result -= a * 10;
                        numbers[i] = result + "" + numbers[i];
                    }
                }
                if(a != 0){
                    numbers[i] = a + "" + numbers[i];
                }
                for(int k = 0; k < i; k++){
                    numbers[i] += "0";
                }
            }
            return longNumberAdditionAlgorithm(numbers);
        }

    private String longNumberAdditionAlgorithm(String[] numbers) {
            String final_number = "0";
            for(int l = 0; l < numbers.length; l++){
                int maxLength = Math.max(final_number.length(), numbers[l].length());
                String number = "";
                int[] n = new int[maxLength];
                int a = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
                    int result = 0;
                    if(i >= final_number.length()){
                        result = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numbers[l].charAt(numbers[l].length() - i - 1)));
                    }else
                    if(i >= numbers[l].length()){
                        result = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(final_number.charAt(final_number.length() - i - 1)));
                    }else{
                        result = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(final_number.charAt(final_number.length() - i - 1))) + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numbers[l].charAt(numbers[l].length() - i - 1)));
                    }
                    if(result + a < 10){
                        number = (result + a) + "" + number;
                        a = 0;
                    }else{
                        result -= 10;
                        number = (result + a) + "" + number;
                        a = 1;
                    }
                }
                if(a == 1){
                    number = a + "" + number;
                }
                final_number = number;
            }
            return final_number;
        }
```