# Unable to calculate factorial , getting output as 0 in C

Tags: c, int, long-integer, factorial, unsigned-integer

Tried calculating factorial of 65, got correct output. Anything greater than 65 results in output of 0. Shocking since I'm using unsigned long int. What is amiss ?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void factorial(int unsigned long);
int main()
{
    int unsigned long num, result;
    printf("\nEnter number to obtain factorial : ");
    scanf("%ld", &num);
    factorial(num);
}
void factorial (int unsigned long x)
{
    register int unsigned long f = 1;
    register int unsigned long i;
    for (i=x;i>=1;i--)
        f= f*i;
    printf("\nFactorial of %lu = %lu\n",x,f);
}
```

Comment: While C **allows** you to write `int unsigned long`, a seasoned programmer never writes that, using instead `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long int`.

Comment: a tip about naming: when using single letter variables, avoid variables that may suggest the wrong type name. For example, the name `f` might lead you to think of the variable as a `float`. As your code becomes longer or more complex, these things become more important.

Comment: How do you know you got the correct output when you calculate 65! ?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Your right, my value for factorial 65 generated by my code is 9223372036854775808 , very off from the real value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly did not get the correct result for 65!  `log2(65!)` is just over 302 bits (Google it), so you'd need a `long int` of at least 303 bits to calculate that correctly.  There is no computer in the world where `long int` is over 300 bits (let's see how this answer ages!).

The largest factorial you can compute in 64 bits is 20! (which is about 2.4e18).

Comment: Well then , how can Google / any other online calculator give the value of factorial of any number above 20 ? Does is break down the 300+ bits into chunks of 64 , like 64 bit is broken down for 32-bit CPUs ?

Comment: @user13863346: They use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: Any way a noob like me could try implementing something similar ?

Comment: Sure, you can use the GMP library: https://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @JohnZwinck, the maximum value for a variable of type unsigned long long (ULLONG_MAX) is 18446744073709551615. So all the values greater than 20! are going to have a garbage value

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19230646/10758654) for more information.

Comment: That's not the maximum value, it is the *minimal maximum value*.

Comment: This does not answer to the question.