# Long doesn't dispaly large numbers and instead outputs random numbers from memory in C

Tags: c

So I have some code to get some large numbers, and I am storing them in `long`, but the output is still not correct because I get negative numbers.

Here is my code:

```
int user_want =0;
long answer=1;
int loop = 0;
printf("What is required?");
scanf("%d", &user_want);
for(loop=1;loop<=user_want; loop++){
  answer = answer*loop
  printf("%ld\n", answer)
}
```

I get this output:

[image]

Pls help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiplication of two integers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662792/multiplication-of-two-integers-in-c)

Comment: See [integer limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/cpp-integer-limits?view=msvc-160).

Comment: What is the value of `LONG_MAX` on your system?

Comment: Use a `long long` if you want that value.

Comment: @RandomDavis Probably better:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230573/cannot-calculate-factorials-bigger-than-20-how-to-do-so  The values are different because the integer type used is `unsigned long long`, but the underlying cause is the same.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I don't know how to check

Comment: @Dock I tried that, it didn't work

Comment: @Albert [Integer limits are defined in the `limits.h` file](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.10).  So if you `#include <limits.h>`, you could then do something like `printf( "LONG_MAX: %ld\n", LONG_MAX );`

Comment: Ok @AndrewHenle I wil try this, it comes out as `2147483647`, this is clearly smaller than what is needed. What should I do?

Comment: This code contains a syntax error and will fail to compile. Please copy and paste your exact code; after reading these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

On most platforms long is the same as int. You need to use long long which uses more bytes (again, on most platforms :-) ). You can print out `sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(long)`, etc. to see how many bytes they use on your platform.
BTW, the numbers you get is simply the result of overflow in the computation.

Comment: I tried `long long` but it didn't work either

Comment: It is going to be correct a bit longer than using just long. If you want it to be correct "forever" then you need to use an infinite precision library, like gmp (https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: I doubt the claim that most platforms have `long` the same size as `int` .  LP64 is very common across desktops and embedded devices now.  LP32 (16-bit int) also was popular in the past