# Getting time elapsed in a C program using clock()

Tags: c, clock

I've been trying to measure time elapsed in a C program using the clock function, but whenever I try to printf any clock values I'm getting back 0. For example:

```
    clock_t time1, time2;
    time1 = clock();
    printf("Time 1 is %d.\n", (int)time1);
    sleep(2);
    time2 = clock();
    printf("Time 2 is %d.\n", (int)time2);
```

In both cases, time1 and time2 print out as 0. I have a feeling it's because I'm using the wrong type in the printf, but every type I've seen doesn't seem to work for me. I've used %Lf, %ld, %f. Can anyone else spot a problem here?

EDIT: I tried most of the types mentioned in this thread: [What’s the correct way to use printf to print a clock_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083142/what-s-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-clock-t) 
I even tried uintmax_t, but without the ability to print p1 and p2, I don't know how to verify if it's a type issue or if clock isn't returning the adequate value.

Comment: Yes, you are right in your thinking. This has already been answered here I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083142/what-s-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-clock-t

Comment: I get output when using either `%d ... (int)`, `%llu ... (unsigned long long)` or `%Lf ... (long double)`. Checkout this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871071/why-c-clock-returns-0

Comment: It might be OS specific. And `clock` is at best returning CPU microseconds, so you need a computation which eats some CPU. On Linux, see [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Answer (score 1):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/)

> Clock program Returns the processor time consumed by the program.
>
> The value returned is expressed in clock ticks, which are units of
>   time of a constant but system-specific length (with a relation of
>   CLOCKS_PER_SEC clock ticks per second).
>
> The epoch used as reference by clock varies between systems, but it is
>   related to the program execution (generally its launch). To calculate
>   the actual processing time of a program, the value returned by clock
>   shall be compared to a value returned by a previous call to the same
>   function.

Basically if your computation time is too small you won't notice anything.

Try adding a while loop from 0 to something big and increment a volatile variable inside it before calling `clock()` a second time.

Comment: I called sleep(2), so that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: sleep probably yields so that your program won't consume any CPU. Why not just try the while loop?