# CLK_TCK undeclared on Mac

Tags: c, macos, time.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

clock_t start, stop;

int main(){
    start = clock();
    function();
    stop = clock();
    double duration = (stop - start)/CLK_TCK;
    return 0;
}
```

I got a problem in Xcode. CLK_TCK undeclared.
how to fix it?

Comment: By using `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`? Please read the man page for `clock()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871071/why-c-clock-returns-0)

Answer (score 2):

Use `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` instead of `CLK_TCK` on mac.

Comment: A copy of comment is not suitable for posts.