# How to print time_t in a specific format?

Tags: c, linux, time, timezone, ls

ls command prints time in this format:

```
Aug 23 06:07
```

How can I convert time received from `stat()`'s `mtime()` into this format for local time?

Comment: analogous for `clock_t`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083142/what-s-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-clock-t

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) (you need to convert `time_t` to `struct tm*` first):

```
char buff[20];
struct tm * timeinfo;
timeinfo = localtime (&mtime);
strftime(buff, sizeof(buff), "%b %d %H:%M", timeinfo);
```

Formats:

```
%b - The abbreviated month name according to the current locale.

%d - The day of the month as a decimal number (range 01 to 31).

%H - The hour as a decimal number using a 24-hour clock (range 00 to 23).

%M - The minute as a decimal number (range 00 to 59).
```

Here is the full code:

```
struct stat info; 
char buff[20]; 
struct tm * timeinfo;

stat(workingFile, &info); 

timeinfo = localtime (&(info.st_mtime)); 
strftime(buff, 20, "%b %d %H:%M", timeinfo); 
printf("%s",buff);
```

Comment: and then use `printf("%s",buff);`?

Comment: Exactly - it will fill the `buff` array with the printable string.

Comment: am not familiar with different time data types. can you tell what the steps should be from stat()

Comment: Well - time_t contains number of the seconds elapsed since 00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970 UTC. `struct tm` contains a calendar date and time broken down into its components.

Comment: No, you can't pass `mtime`. You need to pass `info.st_mtime`  to localtime function.

Comment: Well, it says tm undeclared.
 am i missing some header? i included time.h, stat.h, sys/types.h.

Comment: They all should be inside `#include <time.h>`. I've made a typo in the original post, take look into it now.

Comment: @BlueFlame: Or `fputs(buff, stdout)`

Comment: Do we need free(timeinfo)?