# Working with clock_t in C

Tags: c

I'm working on a little school project to re-code the `SpaceInvaders` Game, without using `ncurses`, but only the basic libraries, and i want to use time to print my screen-buffer every time, so i need to know when to print exactly so the user won't feel the screen lagging.

I started using the `Clock_t` structure as a test like :

```
clock_t stime = clock();
sleep(3);
clock_t etime = clock();
unsigned long millis = ((etime - stime) * 1000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("%lu\n",millis);
```

but the output is 0 all the time, i want know why and how i can fix it so i can see milliseconds, or nanoseconds

Comment: Use a `float` or `double` instead. your result is going to be 0 < r < 1 so it'll be a floating point value. Using a `long` is probably truncating the decimals

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083142/what-s-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-clock-t

Comment: 1) there is no type `Clock_t` 2) `clock_t` is not a structure.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Code is printing a `unsigned long`, not a `clock_t`.  Disagree that the answer in the link applies.

Comment: For investigation, print out the clock values.  `printf("%e %e %e\n", (double)stime, (double)etime, (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);`  I suspect `sleep()` is not sleeping 3 seconds.

Comment: `clock_t stime = clock();
sleep(3);
clock_t etime = clock();
printf("%e %e %e\n", (double)stime, (double)etime, (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
double millis = (double)((etime - stime) * 1000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("%lf\n",(double)millis);`

and the output is
`6.410000e+02 8.020000e+02 1.000000e+06
0.161000`

Answer (score 0):

Add some print statements to your code:

```
clock_t stime = clock();
sleep(3);
clock_t etime = clock();
// print etime and stime and (etime - stime) * 1000 and CLOCKS_PER_SEC
unsigned long millis = ((etime - stime) * 1000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("%lu\n",millis);
```

You will see that the numerator is smaller than the denominator in your expression, therefore since you are using integer math you will truncate the result and it will be zero