# error - time executing in C

Tags: c, execution-time

I'm working in first step of a Project and I have to calculate the executing time of a Summation and a multiplication... I wrote the next code for the summation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  long muestras = 100000000;
  long resultado=0;
  float inicial = clock();
  printf("Tiempo inicial: %f\n",inicial);
  for(int i = 1; i <muestras;i+=1){
    resultado = resultado + i;
  }
  float final = clock();
  printf("Tiempo final: %f\n",final);
  float total = (final-inicial)/((double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  printf("tiempo = %f",total);
  //printf("tiempo = %f",((double)clock() - start));
  printf("\n");
  printf("resultado = %d",resultado);
  return 0;
}
```

and work perfectly, but I wrote the next code for the multiplication, and the initial and final time is 0... I don't know why, I can't understand ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  long muestras = 10;
  long long resultado=1;
  float inicial = clock();
  printf("Tiempo inicial: %f\n",inicial);
  for(int i = 1; i <muestras;i+=1){
    if (resultado>20) {
      resultado = (resultado * i)/20;
    }else{
      resultado = resultado * i;
    }
  }
  float final = clock();
  printf("Tiempo final: %f\n",final);
  float total = (final-inicial);
  ///((double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  printf("tiempo = %f",total);
  //printf("tiempo = %f",((double)clock() - start));
  printf("\n");
  printf("resultado = %lli",resultado);
  return 0;
}
```

I know that have overflow, but no matter what size of samples take, it's the same result.... please help ... sorry for my bad english, greats from Colombia! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value from `clock` is of type `clock_t`, not `float`. Also, the return value is not seconds or anything such, but "clocks", which you can convert to seconds by dividing by clocks per sec.

You should do something like this instead:

```
clock_t initial = clock();
...
clock_t final = clock();
double total = (final - initial) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("time delta = %f", total);
```

Note that [there is no way of printfing a value of type `clock_t` correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083142/what-s-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-clock-t).

Comment: thanks for your answer, it Works for the summation, but I have the same problem with the multiplication .... I increase "muestras" to 100 but the answer is 0 and the time 0 too ...

Answer (score 0):

The return value from `clock()` is of type `clock_t` not `float`, and it represents the number of ticks since the beginning of the program. You should subtract them and then convert to double to divide by CLICKS_PER_SEC, as in Antti's answer.

Also, your multiplication program only executes 10 `muestras`, which means it may entirely finish in the first clock tick. Increase that to a large number and you may see different elapsed time.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it Works for the summation, but I have the same problem with the multiplication .... I increase "muestras" to 100 but the answer is 0 and the time 0 too ...

Comment: try increasing muestras to 100000