# Why does clock_t only give me integers in C

Tags: c, clock

I'm trying to clock a sorting function, pretty straightforward stuff. Code looks like:

```
clock_t start_t, end_t, total_t;
start_t = clock();
sort();
end_t = clock();
total_t = (double)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("sort time: %le", (double)total_t);
```

You could say this works. But, no matter how long it takes I will get an integer output. If sorting 1M elements prints out

```
sort time: 1.000000e+00
```

And sorting 2M elements prints out

```
sort time: 2.000000e+00
```

Then sorting any value of elements between the two will print one of those two outputs. 1.3M elements also takes 1.000000e+00 seconds apparently.

Why is this happening and more importantly how do I fix it?

Comment: Naming variables `xxxx_t` is highly misleading as it's a convention for naming types.

Comment: Straightforward? No, not really. Different platforms assign different semantics to `clock()`,

Comment: You are rounding the output to the number of clocks per second, so your output will always be rounded to seconds

total_t = (double)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

Should be 

total_t = (double)(end_t - start_t);

Comment: @guilleamodeo `(double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` always gives you the number of seconds elapsed between the two times - `(double)(end - start)`, on the other hand, isn't guaranteed to be any useful value.

Comment: Ooops! I didn't mean that, I am missing a chunk in there (itmust sent the post when I pressed the keys to paste instead of pasting) . What I meant is that you need to convert CLOCKS_PER_SEC to double as well...

Comment: `total_t` is an integer variable... you are converting to integer the `double` computed value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assign the result of a `double` computation to `total_t` of type `clock_t`, which may truncate the result as `clock_t` is *usually* an integer type (not guaranteed, but seemingly so on your machine) - it doesn't matter that you then cast back to `double` afterwards when printing.

Just store your result in a `double` instead, [as recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083142/what-s-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-clock-t):

```
double total = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("sort time: %le", total);
```

Comment: Using a `long double` really seems like overkill. Do you really need this computation to be that accurate?

Comment: @rici It was mostly on the recommendation of the post I linked. Prior to your comment I also thought that `long double` was around 64 bits so wouldn't cost much extra, but I've just found out that it's more commonly 80. I'll change this back to `double` as I can't find a compelling reason to use `long double`.

Comment: @rici, indeed the resolution is `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, so probably there are no more than 1000 clocks in a second... so a `float` should suffice.