# Calculate time of Execution for an Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, time, double, mergesort

I am coding in C the algorithm Mergesort. I need to find the execution time of the algorithm for different sized arrays.
But always when I print the time I get `0.0000`.

I searched for this issue and read other stackoverflow questions related to this but it didn't help me. I am still getting same.

My code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b);
void print_array(int *a, int length);
void merge(int *a, int low, int mid, int high);
void merge_sort(int *a, int low, int high);

int swaps = 0;
int comparisons = 0;
int operations = 0;

int main()
{
    int total_operations[1001];
    int num[1001];
    int nlogn[1001];
    double time[1001];

    FILE *input_file = fopen("UniformDis.txt", "r");
    int n = 1;
    for (n = 1; n <= 100; n++)
    {
        int a[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            fscanf(input_file, "%d", &a[i]);
        }

        clock_t t;
        t = clock();
        merge_sort(a, 0, n - 1);
        print_array(a, n);
        t = clock() - t;
        double time_taken = (t * 1000.0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        total_operations[n] = operations + comparisons + swaps;
        num[n] = n;
        nlogn[n] = n * log(n);
        time[n] = t;
        printf("%.50fms\n", t);

        operations = 0;
        comparisons = 0;
        swaps = 0;
    }

    fclose(input_file);
    return 0;
}

void merge_sort(int *a, int low, int high)
{
    operations += 2;
    if (low < high)
    {
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        merge_sort(a, low, mid);
        merge_sort(a, mid + 1, high);
        merge(a, low, mid, high);
    }
}

void merge(int *a, int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int l, r;
    l = mid - low + 1;
    r = high - mid;
    operations += 2;
    int left[l + 1], right[r + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        left[i] = a[low + i];
    }
    operations += l;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        right[i] = a[mid + 1 + i];
    }
    operations += r;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = low;
    while (i < l && j < r)
    {
        comparisons++;
        if (left[i] < right[j])
        {
            a[k] = left[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            a[k] = right[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;

        operations += 6;
    }
    while (i < l)
    {
        a[k] = left[i];
        i++;
        k++;
        operations += 3;
    }
    while (j < r)
    {
        a[k] = right[j];
        j++;
        k++;
        operations += 3;
    }
}

void print_array(int *a, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

OUTPUT -

```
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ms
```

Comment: The code is your question is definitely not producing the output in your question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad :(.
I edited it.

Comment: Consider [POSIX `clock_gettime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html) or equivalent on Windows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083142/what-s-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-clock-t

Comment: Could you please point out what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Sorting 100 items should take on the order of a microsecond, and clock() does not have enough accuracy to measure such small values. You're also printing out the raw clock() value `t` rather than `time_taken` although both are presumably 0 given the output.

Comment: I suggest you move `print_array(a,n);` down a line. You don't want to measure the printing time, just the sorting.

Comment: @PaulHankin: *You're also printing out the raw `clock()` value `t` rather than `time_taken`* Yes indeed, and the conversion specifier is incorrect, which explains the result. The values are non `0` on my laptop, but yours might be faster :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has a bug: `printf("%.50fms\n", t);` you pass a `clock_t` argument for a `%f` conversion which expects its argument from a different place, namely a floating point register which for some reason contains `0.0`. You should write `printf("%.3fms\n", time_taken);` instead.

Also move the `printf("%.3fms\n", time_taken);` after stopping the clock. Printing the array might be more costly than sorting it.

Comment: I tries this but it didn't help :( @chqrlie

Comment: Yes, u were right that I was passing a clock_t variable for %f specifier. 
Now, I am not using clock_t, instead using float and it works fine. @chqrlie